# Strange behavior with DynamicInvoke and Invoke

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, delegates, dynamic-invoke

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116073/can-delegate-dynamicinvoke-be-avoided-in-this-generic-code) post  and I tried to do the same but I came across a very strange behavior when comparing the del.DynamicINvoke(args) Vs. del(args)

**Update**

So after Jon and usr comments i post now new working code.

I'll really appreciate any help!

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostic;
using System.Threading;

namespace DynamicInvokeVsInvoke {
  public class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var objArgs = new object[] {100, 1.2345678 };
      Action<int, double> a = (i, d) => {};
      Action<object[]> action = o => a((int)o[0], (double)o[1]);
      var sw = new Stopwatch();
      sw.Start();
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
         a.DynamicInvoke(objArgs);
      Console.WriteLine("Dynamic: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
      sw.Stop();
      sw = new Stopwatch();
      sw.Start();
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
         action(objArgs);
      Console.WriteLine("Invoke: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
      sw.Stop();
    }
  }
}
```

**Results:**

When 'a' is empty method and the loop runs 1000000 times the DynamicInvoke took approximately 4000 ms and the direct Invoke took 20 ms

When i'm put in a Thread.Sleep(20) and the loop runs 1000 times then the DynamicInvoke and the direct Invoke took approximately 20 seconds

p.s. i can't copy/paste from vs for some reason so i write the code manually if you see syntax error please let me know

Comment: You're not comparing `del.Invoke` with `del.DynamicInvoke`. The delegate you're invoking directly has an extra level of "wrapping" around it. It doesn't explain all the results, but it is a discrepancy between your description and your code.

Comment: @Jon I'm understand but still why if i compare it with empty method the wrapping is about 200 faster then the dynamicinvoke and if the method cobtains body the results changed

Comment: No idea. It's not at all clear why you're using an event or a static initializer in the first place though. Why don't you just have the delegate as a local variable? Your code is unnecessarily complicated at the moment.

Comment: @Jon you right i did it for some reason. I'll edit the code later (im from my mobile now) but i did the comprasion without all the unnecessarily complicated and i got the same strange behavior.

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited my code please check it if you can. thanks!

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for many many reasons. Asking us to explain performance on code that doesn't compile is... unhelpful.

Comment: @Marc narc im sorry this is because i write it in the post and dont copy it from vs. I try to read it again and fix it.

Comment: @Marc Marc i edited my code in vs to make it work and updated the post but for some reason i dont see the update. Anyway i edited now again without vs and im pretty sure its work now. So if you can... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note: when looking at performance always ensure you are running a release/optimized build, and run it **without** the IDE attached. You can usually get away with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> in Visual Studio, but if in doubt: run it from the command line.

> When 'a' is empty method and the loop runs 1000000 times the DynamicInvoke took approximately 4000 ms and the direct Invoke took 20 ms

Fair enough; I get 2729ms for `DynamicInvoke` and 8ms for direct invoke; but that is what we expect; we *know* that `DynamicInvoke` is slower. But everything here is as we expect. In fact, if we correct for the fact that `Invoke` is unfairly running an *extra level* of delegate invoke (which we should expect to roughly-double the time taken), we get:

```
static void Main()
{
    int x = 100;
    double y = 1.2345678;
    var objArgs = new object[] { x, y };
    Action<int, double> a = (i, d) => { };
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    const int loop = 1000000;
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
        a.DynamicInvoke(objArgs);
    Console.WriteLine("Dynamic: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Stop();
    sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
        a(x,y);
    Console.WriteLine("Invoke: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Stop();
}
```

with results:

```
Dynamic: 2785
Invoke: 3
```

So far, nothing unexpected.

> When i'm put in a Thread.Sleep(20) and the loop runs 1000 times then the DynamicInvoke and the direct Invoke took approximately 20 seconds

Yep, 20ms x 1000 is definitely 20 seconds. The 20ms sleep time is not exact; we expect some variance around that number, which adds up when multiplied by 1000. In particular, the sleep interrupt isn't going to fire for every single CPU cycle, so we should probably *expect* the slightly irregular sleep cycle to eat up the difference between a `Invoke` and `DynamicInvoke` (about 2.75 microseconds per call).

Changing `loop` to 1000 and adding a `Thread.Sleep(20)` I get:

```
Dynamic: 20395
Invoke: 20370
```

Again, nothing surprising here. In fact, with the slight randomness introduced by a `Thread.Sleep()`, multiplied by 1000 I would find it perfectly acceptable if `Invoke` occasionally took longer than `Dynamic`.

I see nothing in the least bit surprising in the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the explantion. I tried to put body in the method but not Thread.Sleep() (calculate some values creating list anf dictionary add them objects and get them  some checks etc.) and then if i call it once the results are 273ms to Dynamic and 211ms to Invoke, if i call it 10 times the Dynamic is 1773ms and the Invoke is 1682ms so far no surprise but if i call it 100 times the Dynamic is 18387ms and the Invoke is 18946! and it without the randomness introduced by a Thread.Sleep(). how can i measure if Invoke is really faster in the real application? Thanks again!

Comment: @Maya by timing ;p Actually, there is no question to answer there: it *is* faster. The question is: is the performance difference *important* for your application. If you don't have a performance issue currently, then the answer is "probably not"

Comment: yes its very important, right now all my events fired dynamicly and i have alot of them (hundreds of thousands). anyway i'll change it to Invoke. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is something in your measurement setup that is producing a systematic error. Surely your wouldn't think that using DynamicInvoke makes the *body* of the delegate being invoked faster. It has no impact on the body.

Comment: 10k dynamic invoke calls probably don't take 4.2sec. There is still something wrong. If you post a self-contained repro I'll take a look.

Comment: what do you mean self contained repro?

Comment: A program that I can paste into an empty console application and press F5 to run it.