# Sort Datagridview columns when datasource binded to List(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, generics, generic-list

I have a datagridview with its datasource binded to a List(Of T). Now i would like to sort on any of the columns.

My code:

```
'Database access : items = List(BlogPost)
dgBlogPosts.DataSource = items

'My BlogPost Class
Public Class BlogPost

    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Content As String
    Public Property CreationDate As DateTime
    Public Property Rating As Decimal = 5.0

End Class
```

Comment: datagridview or gridview or datagrid?

Comment: datagridview as described in the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993236.aspx) example which recommends using a BindingList instead and then a bit of code to enable sorting. There is also [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/bindinglist_sortable.aspx) on codeproject.