# How i can sort data in Datagridview by Column name

Tags: c#, winforms

I have LINQ query:

```
var product_view = from productallinfo in QProductAllInfo select productallinfo;
```

Then i load data to table

```
MainCatalog_Table.DataSource = product_view.Distinct();
```

And next i want sort data by column name for example "ProductName"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you sort it before you bind it to the DataSource, something like this:

```
var product_view = from productallinfo in QProductAllInfo 
                   orderby productallinfo.ProductName
                   select productallinfo;
```

And then you bind it to your data source....

Comment: it's i know, but i need sort in DataGridView

Comment: this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns[2], ListSortDirection.Descending); Get exception (InvalidOperationException)

Comment: So you want to sort the GridView, the error you are getting is because you need to bind a source that implements IBindingList, look at this post this shows how you can write your comparer to get around this problem...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377568/c-sharp-datagridview-sorting-with-generic-list-as-underlying-source