# Databinding for JSON.NET objects: how to implement?

Tags: json, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

My application deals a lot with HTTP requests that return JSON data. I use JSON.NET library to handle it.

I need these data to be shown in Winforms databinding controls (mostly `ComboBox` and `DataGridView`). No data editing is intended at the moment, just need to show data in an user-friendly fashion.

I wrote an improvised conversion routine that converts `IEnumerable(Of JToken)` into `DataTable`:

```
Module JsonAsDataTable
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> Public Function ToDataTable(ByVal jtokens As IEnumerable(Of JToken), Optional ByVal trim_object_columns As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal castToCLRtypes As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal orderBy As String = Nothing) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable, sdt As DataTable, dr, sdr As DataRow, dateproperty As Date
        If jtokens IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each jt In jtokens
                dr = dt.NewRow
                For Each jp In jt.Children(Of JProperty)
                    sdt = Nothing
                    If Not dt.Columns.Contains(jp.Name) Then dt.Columns.Add(jp.Name, IIf(castToCLRtypes, GetType(Object), GetType(JToken)))
                    If jp.Value.Type = JTokenType.Object AndAlso jp.Value.Children.Count = 1 AndAlso jp.Value.First.Type = JTokenType.Property AndAlso DirectCast(jp.Value.First, JProperty).Name = "date" Then
                        If Date.TryParse(DirectCast(jp.Value.First, JProperty).Value, dateproperty) Then
                            dr.SetField(jp.Name, New JValue(dateproperty))
                        Else
                            dr.SetField(jp.Name, JValue.CreateNull)
                        End If
                    Else
                        dr.SetField(jp.Name, jp.Value)
                        If jp.Value.Type = JTokenType.Object Then
                            sdt = AsDataTable({jp.Value}, trim_object_columns)
                        ElseIf jp.Value.Type = JTokenType.Array Then
                            sdt = AsDataTable(jp.Value, trim_object_columns)
                        End If
                        If sdt IsNot Nothing Then
                            sdr = sdt.Select.FirstOrDefault
                            For Each sdc As DataColumn In sdt.Columns
                                If Not dt.Columns.Contains(jp.Name & "." & sdc.ColumnName) Then dt.Columns.Add(jp.Name & "." & sdc.ColumnName, GetType(Object))
                                If sdr IsNot Nothing Then dr.SetField(jp.Name & "." & sdc.ColumnName, sdr(sdc.ColumnName))
                            Next
                            If trim_object_columns Then dt.Columns.Remove(jp.Name)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            Next
            If castToCLRtypes Then
                For Each drow In dt.Select
                    For Each dcol As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                        If TypeOf drow(dcol) Is JToken Then drow(dcol) = ToField(drow(dcol))
                    Next
                Next
            End If
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy) Then
                dt = dt.Select("", orderBy).CopyToDataTable
            End If
        End If
        Return dt
    End Function
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> Friend Function ToField(token As JToken) As Object
        If token Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        Select Case token.Type
            Case JTokenType.Boolean
                Return token.Value(Of Boolean)
            Case JTokenType.Bytes
                Return token.Value(Of Byte())
            Case JTokenType.Date
                Return token.Value(Of Date)
            Case JTokenType.Float
                Return token.Value(Of Double)
            Case JTokenType.Guid
                Return token.Value(Of Guid)
            Case JTokenType.Integer
                Return token.Value(Of Integer)
            Case JTokenType.Null
                Return Nothing
            Case JTokenType.Property
                Return ExtractObjectFrom(CType(token, JProperty).Value)
            Case JTokenType.String
                Return token.Value(Of String)
            Case JTokenType.TimeSpan
                Return token.Value(Of TimeSpan)
            Case JTokenType.Uri
                Return token.Value(Of Uri)
            Case Else
                Return token.ToString
        End Select
    End Function
End Module
```

Now I'm aware my solution is neither clean nor reliable. It's just the first thing I thought in order to get things shown in a `DataGridView` in a way user could sort data by clicking column headers, which simple Array of JToken wouldn't allow.

Therefore I'd like to write a custom class that wraps those JToken objects, and perhaps a Collection class to list them in a fashion that `DataGridView` would easily understand and deal with, enabling features like sorting (this is essential to me) and filtering (this would be extra prize to achiev3e).

My question is: *which is **the minimal set of Interfaces** these classes should implement in order to achieve that?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that easy to achieve the sorting of columns with generic Collections like `List<T>` etc. In general `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` is enough to be bound to a GridView from Collection side. Your object don't need to implement any Interface to be shown in the GridView. For sorting you maybe need `ICompareable<T>`. The problem is sorting a Collection isn't that easy as sorting a DataTable. The GridView Component is very poor here. On this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377568/c-sharp-datagridview-sorting-with-generic-list-as-underlying-source) you find many suggestions how to solve sorting with a collection. The examples are C# but should be adaptable. I hope this can help you.