# Data sorting Generic Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I found this great example on sorting data grids with Generic lists here but it seems very slow I only dealing with 2000 records in my List.

[C# DataGridView sorting with Generic List as underlying source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377568/c-sharp-datagridview-sorting-with-generic-list-as-underlying-source)

It also does not appear to handle strings well in sorting does anybody no how I would be able to achieve better results using the below linq.

I am using datagridview in a winforms I no winforms this day and age but not my choice existing application.

```
 private void dgProducts_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
 {
     var compareList = (dgProducts.DataSource as List<StockM>);
     string strColumnName = dgProducts.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
     SortOrder strSortOrder = getSortOrder(e.ColumnIndex);

     if (strSortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
     {
         _allstock = _allstock.OrderBy(x => typeof(StockM).GetProperty(strColumnName).GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
      }
       else
      {
         compareList = compareList.OrderByDescending(x => typeof(StockM).GetProperty(strColumnName).GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
      }

    dgProducts.DataSource = compareList;
    dgProducts.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = strSortOrder;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out if you look at my code where it would hit the descending I was not setting my list correctly.

```
private void dgProducts_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
 var compareList = (dgProducts.DataSource as List<StockM>);
 string strColumnName = dgProducts.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
 SortOrder strSortOrder = getSortOrder(e.ColumnIndex);

 if (strSortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
 {
     _allstock = _allstock.OrderBy(x => typeof(StockM).GetProperty(strColumnName).GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
  }
   else
  {
     compareList = compareList.OrderByDescending(x => typeof(StockM).GetProperty(strColumnName).GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
  }

dgProducts.DataSource = compareList;
dgProducts.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = strSortOrder;

}
```