# Binding a Dictionary to the DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a dictionary item as below

```
Dictionary<string, List<StrikePrice>>
```

where

```
public class StrikePrice
{
    public string Strike { get; private set; }
    public string Price { get; private set; }

    public StrikePrice(string strike, string price)
    {
        Strike = strike;
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

and I wish to assign this dictionary to the `DataGridView`

```
this.dataGridViewTest.DataSource = listSmiles;
```

I understand that a dictionary can't be assigned to the the `DataSource` as this doesn't derive from the `IList` interface.

Is there any way I can assign this dictionary element to the datagrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a bit old, but perhaps it will help someone.  This one line solution worked for  me

```
gridTAV.DataSource = dTAV.Values.ToList<TotalAccountValue>();
```

gridTAV is a DataGridView.  dTAV is a Dictionary.  The key is a date (not important), and the value is a class.

```
Dictionary<DateTime, TotalAccountValue> dTAV = new Dictionary<DateTime, TotalAccountValue>();
```

Since the value was a class the "ToArray()" method did not work for me, since it didn't "unpack" the class properties.

Note that this does not place the KEY in the grid, but I didn't really need that.

Comment: Also, to enable sorting, etc. you can convert the list to a Datatable and bind that instead.  Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable for the code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Values property of the Dictionary?

```
this.dataGridViewTest.DataSource = listSmiles.Values.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes ,by Calling ToArray of Dictionary

```
        var g = this.dataGridView1;
        var s = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        s.Add("1", "Test1");
        s.Add("2", "Test2");
        s.Add("3", "Test3");
        g.DataSource = s.ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

If the question relates to WPF or silverlight, this [article](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/wpf/2009/04/binding-a-silverlight-datagrid-to-dynamic-data-via-idictionary/) gives a solution.

I've been using it and it performs well, even for large numbers of columns.

Comment: @Phillip:
This is for Winforms application.