# Copying Result of Linq into DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, dataset, linq-to-dataset

What changes do i need to make so as to reduce of doing this task with fewer lines and better approach.

```
   DataTable dtStatusMsgs;
    var statusList = (
                    from items in dtInputTable.AsEnumerable()
                    where items.Field<int>("DepartmentId") == deptId
                    select new
                    {
                        statusId = items.Field<int>("StatusId"),
                        status = items.Field<string>("Status"),
                        statusOrder = items.Field<int>("StatusSortOrder"),
                        rowId = items.Field<int>("RowId")

                    }).Distinct();

    dtStatusMsgs = new DataTable();
    dtStatusMsgs.Columns.Add("StatusId", typeof(int));
    dtStatusMsgs.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
    dtStatusMsgs.Columns.Add("StatusSortOrder", typeof(int));
    dtStatusMsgs.Columns.Add("RowId", typeof(int));

    foreach (var item in statusList)
        dtStatusMsgs.Rows.Add(item.statusId, item.status,item.statusOrder
                              , item.rowId);
```

I want it to be done something like this.

```
   DataTable dtStatusMsgs;
    var statusList = (
                    from items in dtInputTable.AsEnumerable()
                    where items.Field<int>("DepartmentId") == deptId
                    select new
                    {
                        statusId = items.Field<int>("StatusId"),
                        status = items.Field<string>("Status"),
                        statusOrder = items.Field<int>("StatusSortOrder"),
                        rowId = items.Field<int>("RowId")

                    }).Distinct();



dtStatusMsgs= statusList.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

And how to use Sum function on any of the column in this code.
I want to see a sample code on this for applying any aggregate function

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/generic-list-to-datatable

Answer (score 1):

```
dtStatusMsgs = new DataTable();     
dtStatusMsgs.Columns.Add("StatusId", typeof(int));     
dtStatusMsgs.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));     
dtStatusMsgs.Columns.Add("StatusSortOrder", typeof(int));     
dtStatusMsgs.Columns.Add("RowId", typeof(int));

statusList.ForEach(p => dtStatusMsgs.Rows.Add(p.StatusId, p.Status, p.StatusSortOrder,p.RowId));
```