# How can i Convert Generic List into dataTable?

Tags: c#

I have 4 list. I want to convert these lists into Datatable with 4 columns. Each list assigned into corresponding column into DataTable.

```
List<string> list1;
List<string> list2;
List<string> list3;
// and 
List<string> list4;
```

this i want to convert datatable as

columns:  List1 List2 List3 List4

Can anyone tell me Easy Solution for this?

Comment: Do lists have a relation between eachother?

Comment: Unless you can prove it will save the world, I'm going to go with no

Comment: duple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/generic-list-to-datatable

Comment: how to you want to flatten the objects in the lists if you don't use primitive datatypes (such as int, string, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haven't tried it outside of just making sure it builds, runs, and seems to populate the datatable fine.

```
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Col1", list1.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First());
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Col2", list2.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First());
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Col3", list3.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First());
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Col4", list4.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First());

        // assumes they all match on count
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(list1[i], 
                               list2[i],
                               list3[i],
                               list4[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Actually, he already said the lists are all strings, so you can skip the reflection.  The only other issue I see offhand is that the lists might be of different lengths, but that's something he's going to have to worry about.  With his awful design.

Comment: Yes i tried this way this ok...but i want to Do new way to add the list into datatable...