# DataBoundItem using DataView

Tags: c#, .net

I've the following problem: I have a list "lst" of "Person" objects, and I put them in a DataGridView using a Dataview object ( I need it for filters )

```
        DataTable dt = Request.ListToDataTable(lst);
        dw = new DataView(dt);
        dw.Sort = "age ASC";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dw;
```

When I click a button, I need to get the value of a field of the Person class that I put in  a hidden column, relative to the selected row. To do that, I use :

```
        Person val = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as Person;
        Debug.WriteLine(val.id);
```

but when I run the program, the result is a crash, probably because the bound item is not  a Person object but a DataTable element. Can somebody point me out how can I get that element? If the colum wasn't hidden it would have been easy, but this way I can't figure out how to obtain it!
Thanks to everybody

Comment: do lst.Sort(); dataGridView1.DataSource = lst; instead of current code.

Comment: I need DataView to easily add and remove filters to the datagrid elements

Comment: Where does `Request.ListToDataTable()` come from? Anyway, that seems to be where your Person objects are converted to DataRows. You can't cast back.

Comment: ListToDataTable is the function shown here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/generic-list-to-datatable . Even if i can't cast back, can i look at the correct datatable row ? in there the column i'm interested in is included...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need something like:

```
var row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRow;
var val = row[X] as MyType;
```

Second attempt:

```
var drv = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
var row = drv.Row as DataRow;
var val = row[X] as MyType;
```

Comment: When I press the button, the row variable is null, even if I selected a row from the datagrid.

Answer (score 4):

That is becuase , you are binding DataView to the DataGridView so the item collection will be of type DataRowView , to get it correctly .

```
DataRowView drv =   dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView ;

Now get the associated Row 

if(drv != null)
  {
    DataRow row = drv.Row;

   // Now get the respective column value say PersonId and assuming PersonId is a column in the bounded DataView

    if(row!=null)
      {
        var personId = row["PersonId"];
      }
  }
```