# how to sort a DataGridView on edit the coulmn value in winforms using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to sort the datagridview. when user did some changes into datagrid from this event CellValueChanged.
after the CellValueChanged completes the datagridview should be sort according to that column. i have bind datagrid with list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ColumnIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.columnindex.aspx) property from [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.aspx) to [sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z.aspx)

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.CellValueChanged +=new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col1"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col2"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col3"));

        var r1 = dt.NewRow();
        r1["col1"] = "a1";
        r1["col2"] = "b1";
        r1["col3"] = "c1";

        var r2 = dt.NewRow();
        r2["col1"] = "a2";
        r2["col2"] = "b2";
        r2["col3"] = "c2";

        var r3 = dt.NewRow();
        r3["col1"] = "a3";
        r3["col2"] = "b3";
        r3["col3"] = "c3";

        dt.Rows.Add(r1);
        dt.Rows.Add(r2);
        dt.Rows.Add(r3);

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dt;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
        var dataGridColumn = dataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
        dataGrid.Sort(dataGridColumn, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }
```

Comment: private void datagrid_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {                                                                   ......
((DataGridView)sender).Sort(((DataGridView)sender).Columns["dgvcOperateur"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
}                                                                    this code gives error. can u give some example or sample code. for sort a datagrid on cellvaluechanged.

Comment: DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted.

Comment: It's because your `DataGridView` is trying to sort the collection itself, which appears not to be sortable. what type is your `DataGridView.DataSource`?

Comment: List<T> objSource=new List<T>();                          DataGridView.DataSource= objSource;

Comment: List<T> objSource=new List<T>(); DataGridView.DataSource= objSource;                                                       got same error "DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted"

Comment: if you want automatic sorting, your collection must implement `IBindingListView `. have a look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702014/sorting-datagridview-datasource-on-listt-where-t-is-anonymous)

Comment: List<student> lststudent=new List<student>(); DataGridView.DataSource= lststudent; got same error "DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted"

Comment: Should i use SortableBindingList method? Could u please help me.

Comment: If you insist on `List<T>` you can create custom one by extending it: `class MySortableList<T> : List<T>, IBindingListView{}` if not then as far as I'm aware your only options are `DataTable` and `ListView`