# join two datatable and return the result in another data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, inner-join

Q:

I have two data tables and i wanna to inner join the and return the result in a another datatable through LINQ.

```
DataTable dt1 = StaffCVDAL.getCourses(int.Parse(Session["emp_num"].ToString()));
DataTable dt2 = cc1lectcrsfilesDAL.ListFiles(int.Parse(Session["emp_num"].ToString()), int.Parse(Session["permission_code"].ToString()));
DataTable dt = from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
               join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                      on t1["crsnum"] equals t2["crsnum"]
               select new { t1["crsname"],t2["group"] }; //the problem is here .
```

Comment: Is there an explicit need that the result should be a `DataTable`? The LINQ returns a `IEnumerable` of the anonymous type you created.

Comment: yeah i need the result in a `datatable` and this is the problem.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a sql view?

Comment: hmm, just i wanna the result in more performance way to be the data source of my gridview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the query expression (LINQ) returns an `IEnumerable` of the anonymous type you created, instead of a `DataTable`. IMHO, I prefer working with collections instead of datatables, but if you want to have a DataTable, you can create and populate it yourself from the collection, like this:

```
var collection = from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                 join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                    on t1["crsnum"] equals t2["crsnum"]
                 select new { Name = t1["crsname"], Group = t2["group"] }; 
DataTable result = new DataTable("NameGroups");
result.Columns.Add("crsname", typeof(string));
result.Columns.Add("group", typeof(int));

foreach (var item in collection)
{
   result.Rows.Add(item.Name, item.Group);
}
```

for more details, and a more general solution, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/generic-list-to-datatable).

Comment: ` select new { t1["crsname"],t2["group"] }` this part make a compile error---> `invalid anonymous type member declarator`.

Comment: of course it does :). Poor C# cant figure what the names of the fields should be. Will edit the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot but when i trace i find the `collection` is empty while the `inner` yields result !!.