# C# join two datatables using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, excel, linq, datatables

I have 2 datatables:

1. DataTable table1 --> importing data from Excel file

Sample data:

```
Account, Name, Address, Phone 
A05911,  Test1, LA,    1234
A05912,  Test2, NY,    1235
A05912,  Test2, NY,    1235
A05913,  Test3, BO,    1239
```

2. DataTable table2 -- importing data from SQL database

Sample data:

```
 Account, Dummy
 A05911,  yyyy1
 A05912,  xxxx2
 A05913,  zzzz3
```

I want to join these 2 datatables so the resulting datatable will be:

```
Account, Dummy, Name, Address, Phone 
A05911,  yyyy1, Test1, LA,    1234
A05912,  xxxx2, Test2, NY,    1235
A05912,  xxxx3, Test2, NY,    1235
A05913,  zzzz4, Test3, BO,    1239
```

I have tried with following query:

```
var result = ( from a in table1.AsEnumerable(),
                     join b in table2.AsEnumberable()
                     on a.Field<string>("Account") equals b.Field<string>("Account") 
                 into temp from res in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new 
                 {
                      Account = a.Field<string>("Account"),
                      Test = res == null ? null : res.Field<string>("Dummy")
                 });
```

But this query does not give all the columns from table1 and 'Dummy' column from table2. It only returns 'Account' from table1 and its 'Dummy' from table2.

How do I achieve this and also how do I store this query result into a datatable?

I want the following result in datatable:

```
Account, Dummy, Name, Address, Phone 
A05911,  yyyy1, Test1, LA,    1234
A05912,  xxxx2, Test2, NY,    1235
A05912,  xxxx3, Test2, NY,    1235
A05913,  zzzz4, Test3, BO,    1239
```

Comment: What's the logic behind writing `a.Field<string>("Account").ToString()`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add them to your `select`:

```
 select new 
 {
      Account = a.Field<string>("Account"),
      Name = a.Field<string>("Name"),
      Address = a.Field<string>("Address"),
      Phone = a.Field<string>("Phone"),
      Test = res == null ? null : res.Field<string>("Dummy")
 });
```

Comment: So, the columns in table1 can vary except the Column 'Account'. So I need to select all the columns from table1 and 'Dummy' column from table2.
Also, the result of this query is IEnumerable<a>. How do I convert it to store in DataTable variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609732

Comment: Define the columns in the new datatable and add rows from `result`