# How to bulk insert data into db using Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the past, I always use Class `SqlBulkCopy` to complete bulk insert. But I don't know how to implement it using Linq to SQL. If inserted one by one, Efficiency will be very low.
Any good ideas? 
Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: you don't. You just use `SqlBulkCopy`. LINQ-to-SQL is simply a tool. `SqlBulkCopy` is a tool. Use the right tool for each job. Sometimes that means using something that *isn't* LINQ-to-SQL. This might mean creating a `DataTable` (or a spoof `IDataReader` if you are feeling ambitious) to represent the data; look perhaps at [Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/generic-list-to-datatable) to get from your typed objects to a `DataTable` you can feed to `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: +1. O/R mappers serve a specific need. Dont't abuse a tool. SqlBulkCopy is unbeatable for bulk inserts.

Answer (score 0):

See this article on [SubmitChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378.aspx).

> Your changes are not transmitted to the server until you explicitly call SubmitChanges on the DataContext.

Comment: Submitchanges does not do bulkinsert, but one insert statement per record.

Comment: @Pleun: Thanks, I didn't realize.