# List of entities to datatable

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, datatable

I have a list of entities which contain some of it fields as other entities.

Eg.

```
MyEntity
Int id
ContactEntity Contact -> contactId, Name etc…
AddressEntity Address
```

So I have `List< MyEntity>` which needs to be converted to a data table. But from the sub entities I want only one field to be selected.

Is it possible or do I have any other alternative.

**UPDATE**

When I try ***CopyToDataTable()*** as ivowiblo describes it gives me following error

```
 The type 'AnonymousType#1' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or
 method 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'.
 There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Data.DataRow'.
```

Comment: Related: [Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/564366/3258851)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx they explain how to implement a `CopyToDataTable()` method that doesn't need the type to be a DataRow for working with, for instance, entities.

Just create a query that returns the desired schema and use `CopyToDataTable()` method:

```
var table = entities.Select(x => new {
                                       x.Id,
                                       Contact = x.Contact.Name,
                                       Address = x.Address.Address
                                      }).CopyToDataTable();
```

The only issue with this solution is that it uses reflection and it may hit the performance, depending on the load of you application. If you need to avoid reflection, you will need to create a method that explicitly creates the DataTable from you entities:

```
var table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int))
table.Columns.Add("Contact", typeof(string))
table.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string))

foreach(var entity in entities) {
    var row = table.NewRow();
    row["Id"] = entity.Id;
    row["Contact"] = entity.Contact.Name;
    row["Address"] = entity.Address.Address;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: I find the [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) library by Marc Gravell very useful for this task. Refer to the related question to see how it can be done.

Comment: @Marc.2377 full sample using FastMember about it?

Comment: @Kiquenet See link in comment under the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code (with CopyToDataTable function):

```
var query = ....
DataTable dataTable = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen the **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx**, problem is I have sub entities within the entity and I only need to extract one filed from those

Comment: This is not converting "a list of entities" like the question asked.