# How to use HyperDescriptor to fasten the conversion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, .net-3.5, datatable

I have a list of objects as the following :

```
List<UserTransactionDTO>
```

---

and i want to convet this list to a `Datatable` .

I search  and found the following link :

[Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable)

It works for me but i don't know how to implement `HyperDescriptor` to make it faster .Is there some dll  to use ?

---

I just use the following code in the previous link and it works fine  :

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < props.Count ; i++)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }
    object[] values = new object[props.Count];
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    return table;        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple. Reference the HyperDescriptor library in your project, and call this once per type, in your application initialization to make the descriptor for each type "hyper":

```
Hyper.ComponentModel.HyperTypeDescriptionProvider.Add(typeof(MyType))
```

Alternatively, you can use my version of `HyperTypeDescriptionProvider` that I provided in the project comments: [HyperDescriptor at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18450/HyperDescriptor-Accelerated-dynamic-property-acces?msg=4510470#xx4510470xx). It fixes a couple issues I found, including a stack overflow problem when trying to add a type and its base type to `HyperTypeDescriptionProvider`. If you do that, you can simply do the `Add()` call in your function, and bad things won't happen because a second call with the same type will not add the type twice in my version. At the top of your `ToDataTable<T>()` function, add the line:

```
Hyper.ComponentModel.HyperTypeDescriptionProvider.Add(typeof(T))
```

Whichever way you do it, don't forget to do benchmarking tests before/after to make sure you are getting the performance benefit.

P.S. I'd like to thank [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/) very much for his work on HyperDescriptor, which I regard as some very spiffy and useful wizardry.

Comment: This totally solved my problem with the StackOverflowException I was having.  Thanks Matt.