# Filling datatable with LINQ to Entity results so I can iterate though them

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5

I have been trying to fill up a datatable with the LINQ results so I can iterate though the DT and print out the needed data but no matter how I try it cant convert the anonomus type into a datatable.

The LINQ I am using is:

```
        using (var db = new SiteNavigation())
        {
            dtNavData=  (from n in db.Navigation
                         join st in db.SectionTranslations
                         on n.SectionID equals st.Section.SectionID
                         where n.Category == Category && st.CultureID == CultureID
                         orderby n.Position ascending
                         select new
                         {
                              LinkAddress = st.Section.Type + "/" + st.Section.RouteName,
                              st.Title
                          }).ToList();
        }
```

Is there some way to get the results into a datatable or any other object so I can step though it row by row and process the data?

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable)

Comment: Is there nothing more effecent? I do not care if the data is in a table or not. I just need to step though the results and assign them to different asp.net objects in the aspx page.

Comment: so why cannot you iterate through your list in a foreach loop?

Comment: Becasue I get the same can not convert from anonymis error. No matter what I try to full with the LINQ query it can not convert from anonymis

Comment: exactly, when you do select in your linq query, it becomes anonymous type. why are you trying to covert it? take the result of your query in var myresult = (from n in db...) and iterate through myresult

Comment: Ok how do I iterate though the var myresult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to create a `DataTable`, if all that you want is to iterate through the result of your linq query

```
var myResult =  (from n in db.Navigation
                     join st in db.SectionTranslations
                     on n.SectionID equals st.Section.SectionID
                     where n.Category == Category && st.CultureID == CultureID
                     orderby n.Position ascending
                     select new
                     {
                          LinkAddress = st.Section.Type + "/" + st.Section.RouteName,
                          st.Title
                      }).ToList();


foreach(var item in myResult)
{
     string linkAddrs = item.LinkAddress;
     string title = item.Title;
}
```