# How to add new rows to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i'm making ASP.net application and i want to have some kind of table there. I tried using Grindview, but when i  try to add second new row (from code), the second row replaces first row.

here is code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("thing", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("thing2", typeof(string));
            }
            DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
            NewRow[0] = label1.Text;
            NewRow[1] = label2.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

I'm expecting Gridview with 2 rows and button which gives you new row with every click.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code that you're using to add rows.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if your "add button" is part of your gridview... this can be tough to work with...

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you exactly asking or trying to do but this might help

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

  {

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
   {
       dt.Columns.Add("nameofcolumn1", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("nameofcolumn2", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("nameofcolumn3", typeof(string));
   }

   DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
   NewRow[0] = value1;
   NewRow[ 1] = value2;
   dt.Rows.Add(NewRow); 
   GridView1.DataSource = dt;
   GridViewl.DataBind();

   }
```

visit this link also
[Add row datagridview at every button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054612/add-row-datagridview-at-every-button-click)

Comment: When I click a button, this code makes Gridview with one row, when i click again, the new row replaces the old row. The second row must stay below the first row.

Comment: Check the link below that will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can add rows using a loop, where you create the row, add the content and then add the row to the datatable.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
{
     dt.Columns.Add("thing", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("thing2", typeof(string));
}

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
     dr[0] = "foo";
     dr[1] = "bar";
     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Then bind the datatable to your GridView:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridViewl.DataBind();
```

Comment: @TrotlOtl - did you add the columns beforehand?  It's working for me without error.

Answer (score 1):

if you have your front hand HTML asp.net code that define your gridview's style (here's an exemple) :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grvModel"  runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#eeeeee" BackColor="#aaccff"  AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button id="btnDel" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="btnDel_click" runat="server"Text="Delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="lblWrite" Text='write here' />
                </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Then all you have to do is create a `List<>` of object and bind it to your gridView, if you want to add somthing, just add to the list and bind it again (hers's an exemple) :

```
List<aClass> classList;

protected void BindFirstTime(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    classList= new List<aClass>();
    classList.Add(new aClass("one"));
    classList.Add(new aClass("two"));
    Grv.DataSource = classList;
    Grv.DataBind();
}

protected void AddObject(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    classList.Add(new aClass("three or more !"));
    Grv.DataSource = classList;
    Grv.DataBind();
}
```

This is the simple way for me, hope it helps.

Comment: What exactly is aClass and db?

Comment: sorry, aClass is a class, any class you've made, and you weren't suposed to see db at all, my mistake, but if you'r curious, it was Entity-Linq code, and i use it to query a database. By using the db object you saw, i can show datas (from a database) in a gridview with a few lines of code... A nice thing, fast and easy

Comment: And what should i place instead of aClass? string? Sorry, but I don't understand this..

Comment: You have to look at your gridview design, if it requires a propertys like (id, name, age) then your class must have a property called id, another one called name, and another one called age. exemple of a property : `string name {get; set;}`

Comment: Now that i think of it, could you show the design of your gridview in you'r question ?

Comment: Gridview design? It looks just like default gridview when you drag and drop it from toolbox. And what do you mean with "if it requires a propertys" ? It doesn't require nothing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115759/discussion-between-trotlotl-and-antoine-pelletier).