# convert linq query results to datatable C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to convert the linq query results to datatable so that I can assign datatable to GridView to show it on asp page.

However I am not able to convert the results to datatable, I am not getting CopyToTable() method in my code.

please advise what am I doing wrong here?

```
 var gradeData = (from data in oAngieCtxt.prc_ShopInstanceCustomersData(Convert.ToInt32(this.ShopInstanceID), 10000, false)
                     .Where( row => row.RecievedPoints != "n/a" )
                    .GroupBy(row => new { row.Name })
                    .Select(g => new GroupedPoints()
                    {
                        Name = g.Key.Name,
                        TotalPoints = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.RecievedPoints) * (x.Weightage.ToString() == "0.00" ? 1 : Convert.ToDouble(x.Weightage)))
                    })
                     select data).ToList();

 DataTable dt = gradeData --gradeData.CopyToTable()
```

Note: reference to dataextentions dll is available.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get [DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx)

Remove `ToList()`.

CopyToDataTable is an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` extension (unfortunately).

There is a solution with custom CopyToDataTable extension method below.

```
var gradeData = (from data in oAngieCtxt.prc_ShopInstanceCustomersData(
                 Convert.ToInt32(this.ShopInstanceID), 10000, false)
                .Where( row => row.RecievedPoints != "n/a" )
                .GroupBy(row => new { row.Name })
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    Name = g.Key.Name,
                    TotalPoints = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.RecievedPoints) 
                    * (x.Weightage.ToString() == "0.00" ? 1 
                      : Convert.ToDouble(x.Weightage)))
                })
                 select data);

var dt = gradeData.CopyToDataTable();
```

**Edit:**

Here is a more useful implementation of [CopyToDataTable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aconrad/archive/2007/09/07/science-project.aspx) There is no type constraint to DataRow.

```
  public static class DataSetLinqOperators
  {
    public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        //you find the ObjectShredder implementation on the blog wich was linked.
        return new ObjectShredder<T>().Shred(source, null, null);
    }

    public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                     DataTable table, LoadOption? options)
    {
        return new ObjectShredder<T>().Shred(source, table, options);
    }

  }
```

Comment: getting the error: Error 7 The type 'uc_report.GroupedPoints' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'uc_report.GroupedPoints' to 'System.Data.DataRow'. C:\Users\DEV7\Documents\csdev\trunk\DWIZA\UserControls\stealth\report.ascx.cs 223 24 C:\...\DWIZA\

Comment: try without the class anonymous way. Modified above.

Comment: thanks for the reply anyways i cannot find any modifications,what did u modify?

Comment: new GroupedPoints(){} => new {}

Comment: the problem, you need to have a IEnumerable<DataRow>() to use this method

Comment: Later, I can find a good solution to your problem, but I don't have time now.

Comment: Here is an implementation of a Custom CopyToDataTable extension method, which is more useful then original: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aconrad/archive/2007/09/07/science-project.aspx implement it in a static class, and you can use it immediately with a simple IEnumerable.

Answer (score 5):

First declare a new DataTable and add columns, in this :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
DataRow row = null;
```

Now I simply iterate through the query and fill a DataTable:

```
foreach (var rowObj in query)
{
    row = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(rowObj.FirstName, rowObj.LastName);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have you own extension method then you could always do something like this:

```
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IQueryable items)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type)
                                  .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                                  .Where(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.PropertyType.Namespace.Equals("System"))
                                  .Where(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.IsReadOnly == false)
                                  .ToArray();

        var table = new DataTable();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(propertyInfo.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) ?? propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(props.Select(property => property.GetValue(item)).ToArray());
        }

        return table;
    }
```

You will need to reference both of these

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
```