# Cannot implicitly convert type 'IQueryable<> to IQueryable<DataRow>

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio

I am trying to write a simple save and load operation using EDMX in Visual Studio 2008.

This is my load method:

```
    public static DataTable LoadData()
    {

    using (testEntities context = new testEntities())
      { 

              testEntities temp = new testEntities();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

       IQueryable<DataRow> empResults = (from c in temp.emplyee
                                          select c).AsQueryable();


       }


        return dt;
    }
```

However I receive the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

I am not able to find any exact link for this conversion.

Comment: What is the type of `temp.emplyee`?

Comment: If you're using Linq-to-Entities, you don't need `DataTable` nor `SqlDataAdapter` by the way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert linq query results to datatable C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608959/convert-linq-query-results-to-datatable-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 IQueryable<DataRow> empResults = (from c in temp.emplyee
                                   select c).Cast<DataRow>().AsQueryable();
```

But ensure that `temp.emplyee` is `DataRow`

---

So if you are using EF you need to use generated models and context, not adapters and dataTable

Comment: temp.employee is System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<emplyee> .I Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast that directly, `CopyToDataTable` should help you though:

```
DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T> Method (IEnumerable<T>)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx

Or you can implement a custom method to populate `DataRow` columns with properties of you entity.