# How to get value by column name entity framework linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of column names. I want to iterate fetched data using list of column names, so what generic type should I use to convert fetched data into?

Edit:

```
List<string> columns = new List<string>();
columns.Add("column1");
columns.Add("column2");
columns.Add("column3");

string joinColumns = string.Join(",", columns);
string sql = "select "+joinColumns+" from Table";
```

It will fetched only selected columns, So how would I do same functionality using entity framework instead of using sql query?

Thanks in advance.
Help is appreciated.

**Solution-**
This is not possible in link so alternative to this, I converted List to DataTable using extension method described in the link - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805044/1416033

```
List<string> columns = new List<string>();
columns.Add("column1");
columns.Add("column2");
columns.Add("column3");

List<Accounts> accountList = GetAccountList();
DataTable dt = accountList.ToDataTable<Accounts>();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   foreach (string column in columns)
   {
      val = dr[column].ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: context.Table.Where should return an IQueryable of the Table model classes.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely I know it will return IQueryable but if I want to access  that fetched data by column name then into what generic type should I convert my fetched data?

Comment: If you append a .ToList() at the end, it will return a List<Table> that will persist outside of the method's scope. Table should have all the columns you have in the database, by default.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely If I get data into .ToList(), that list contains one of the column XYZ, then how come I access that 'XYZ' column value directly?

Comment: you can use an anonymous type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe isn't going to work with native LINQ functionality.  There is a library though, that should help you.  Check out Dynamic LINQ: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: I didn't know that it is not possible in LINQ. So thanks for the info. I didn't use Dynamic LINQ instead I use extension method, I have updated my question with solution.