# How to convert List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>( ); to DataTable?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a list

```
List<> list = new List<>();
```

I want to convert this to a data table.How it is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The following is the method through which you can convert any list object to datatable..***

```
 public DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
           TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;

    }
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ffcb247-77fb-40b4-bcba-08ba377ab9db/converting-a-list-to-datatable?forum=csharpgeneral