# Facing issues on converting list to datatable c#

Tags: c#

I have below code and facing issues on converting list to datatable. 
This line gives error.  **DataTable studentTable = Students;**

```
public DataTable GetDetails()
        {

            List<Student> Students = new List<Student>(){
                new Student() { Name = "Jack", Age = 1, StudentId = 100 },
                new Student() { Name = "Smith", Age = 2, StudentId = 101 },   
                       new Student() { Name = "Smit", Age = 3, StudentId = 102 },};
            DataTable studentTable = Students;// This line gives error.
        }

        public class Student
        {
            public string Name;
            public int Age;
            public int StudentId;
        }
```

Please correct me.

Comment: Type `List<Student>` cannot be assigned to the type `DataTable`. Pretty simple error, I suppose.

Comment: C# is a strongly type language. You cannot assign variables to a instance of different type. That's pretty obvious...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable)

Comment: Please can someone suggest to edit the code and correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making lists, you should make columns and then add rows.

```
Studenttable.columns.add("Name", typeof(string));
Studenttable.columns.add("Agg", typeof(int));
Studenttable.columns.add("StudentID", typeof(int));

Studenttable.Rows.add("Jack",1,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. You must convert it first. C# doesn't allow you to assign different type of value to each other.

```
 public DataTable GetDetails()
    {

        List<Student> Students = new List<Student>(){
            new Student() { Name = "Jack", Age = 1, StudentId = 100 },
            new Student() { Name = "Smith", Age = 2, StudentId = 101 },   
                   new Student() { Name = "Smit", Age = 3, StudentId = 102 },};
        DataTable studentTable = new DataTable();// Changed
       using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(Students)) 
          {
            studentTable.Load(reader);
          }
       return studentTable; //need it?
    }
```

Sorry if it doesn't work see more [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable).