# Generalize converting a Linq-to-SQL object representing a table to a DataTable

Tags: c#, reflection, linq-to-sql

I have the following class:

```
    [Table(Name = "test")]
    public class Test
    {
        private string _Name;
        [Column(Storage = "_Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this._Name; }
            set { this._Name = value; }
        }

        private int _Age;
        [Column(Storage = "_Age")]
        public int Age
        {
            get { return this._Age; }
            set { this._Age = value; }
        }

        public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<Test> table) // Used for SqlBulkCopy
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

            foreach (Test row in table)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Name"] = row.Name;
                dr["Age"] = row.Age;

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            return dt;
        }
    }
```

But I'd like to abstract that `ConvertListToDataTable` method out into a parent base class. Is that possible using reflection? I wouldn't even know where to start.

Note the DataTable will have columns that exactly match (in name without the `_` and type) all the properties of the class with a [Column] attribute

---

This is the reason I want the `DataTable`:

```
public void testBulkInsert(string connection, string table, DataTable dt)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table;

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/564373/961113) from Marc Gravell, that has a generic method to convert `List<T>` to datatable.

Comment: @Habib so... I can use his second code block but instead of as an extension method, use it directly inside my bulk insert function and just pass a `List<object>` instead of a `DataTable`?

Comment: I would suggest you have to it as an extension method, and you can use it with any `IList<T>`. In your case once you have extension method set, then you can call your method like: `testBulkInsert(connectionString, tableName, table.ToToDataTable())`

Comment: Dan, if that doesn't solve your issue, or you are looking for something different then please let me know, I will vote to reopen the question.

Comment: @Habib thanks - I might only get to try this on Monday. But I'll give it a shot

Comment: @Habib Thanks - while I don't understand the code, it does the job!

Comment: @Habib I'm actually getting an error if I try use a `Decimal?` type at the line `table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);` of the code you linked to. Any idea how to make this work for nullable types?

Comment: See the next answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5805044/961113

Comment: Oops sorry, I'll read that now! Thanks!