# How to make an anonymous type property nullable in the select of a linq to sql query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, nullable

Consider this simplified example query:

```
dt = (
  from O in ...
  ...
   select new
   {
      O.A,
      B = 0
   }).ToList().ToDataTable()
```

Where `.ToDataTable()` comes from [Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable/5805044#5805044)

Assuming that table `O` does not have an attribute called `B` but I want to have a column called `B` whose values I will fill in later. This works fine when `B` get number values sent to it but i actually want to send it `int?` values and at present it crashes if it gets send a `null`.

Is there a way to select a new column (e.g. `B`) such that it is a nullable type?

Comment: Shouldn't `B = ((Nullable<int>)null)` work?

Comment: You just set `B = 0`, how does it crash? I don't understand.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå thanks, I got it working this way. Had to do some casting to `object` later on though because the `DataTable` I put this in wants `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`. But it works. Thanks!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it crashes later on when I manually try asign `null` to column `B` (which is in a `DataTable` by then)

Comment: You can't assign anonymous type's properties once it is created. It is immutable. How does the `DataTable` comes to picture here? Your question is unclear really.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel sorry, edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
var testNull = (from student in studentList
                select new
                {
                    RollNo = default(int?),
                    Name = student.Name
                }).ToList();
```

But better we can create concrete type instead of depending upon a anonymous type based on value.:-)

Comment: What do you mean by that last sentence please?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select new
{
    O.A,
    B = (int?)0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the type of anonymous type members is inferred make it infer the right thing: `B = (int?)null`.

Not sure what you mean by "fill in later". If you want `B` to be mutable you need to create a class.

Comment: Apologies, by "fill it in later" I mean I convert `q` to a DataTable and then manually assign values into column `B` of the `DataTable`