# Show List of MyClass to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to display all the data from my List of `MyClass` to a `DataGridView` for troubleshooting purposes. So I implemented the code below (from Marc Gravell's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/564373/3852958)) in my application. It executes, but despite the fact that my List contains data, the props.Count and values.Length are always 0. So the DataTable returned has no rows or columns.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }
    object[] values = new object[props.Count];
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    return table;
}
```

**My calling code:**

```
dgv.DataSource = Globals.ToDataTable(Lines_Formatted);
```

**My Class:**

```
public class LineData
{
    public string RowID = "";
    public bool MissingMatchingPunch = false;
    public bool ScheduleIssueWithPunches = false;
    public bool ScheduledTimeAmountMet = true;
    public bool Approved_TimeEntry = true;
    public bool Approved_PunchIn = true;
    public bool Approved_PunchOut = true;
    public DateTime DateApplicable = DateTime.MinValue;
    public string TimeType = "";
    public int TimeType_CID = -1;
    public Double HoursWorked = 0;
    public double Amount = 0;
    public DateTime PunchIn = DateTime.MinValue;
    public DateTime PunchOut = DateTime.MinValue;
    public Double DailyTotal = 0;
    public Double CumulativeTotal = 0;
    public string EnteredBy = "";
    public LineType LineTypeKey;
    public enum LineType
    {
        PunchEntry = 1,
        TimeEntry = 2,
        BlankLine = 5
    }
    public string CID_Time = "";
    public string CID_PunchIn = "";
    public string CID_PunchOut = "";
    public string Account_CID = "";
}
```

Comment: Why you ever convert the nice list that you have to a obsolete data table? Why not simple `dgv.DataSource = Lines_Formatted;`

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Just tried that Ivan. Same result: blank DataGridView.

Comment: Then you probably do not have a **public** properties in your class, do you? It would be easier if you show the class and the list declarations.

Comment: @IvanStoev Added the code of my class above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You class contains only **fields**. The code you are using, and data binding and `TypeDescriptor` services in general require **public properties**.

To fix the problem, turn your fields into auto properties. If you are using C#6 (VS2015), it will be simple inserting `{ get; set; }` like this

```
public class LineData
{
    public string RowID { get; set; } = "";
    public bool MissingMatchingPunch { get; set; } = false;
    public bool ScheduleIssueWithPunches { get; set; } = false;
    // ....
}
```

If you are on older C# version, you need to add `{ get; set; }` part, but move the initialization in the class constructor.

```
public class LineData
{
    public string RowID { get; set; }
    public bool MissingMatchingPunch { get; set; }
    public bool ScheduleIssueWithPunches { get; set; }
    // ....

    public LineData()
    {
        RowID = "";
        MissingMatchingPunch = false;
        ScheduleIssueWithPunches = false;
        // ...
    }
}
```

You don't need to initialize properties with default values like `false` for `bool` and `0` for `int` etc.

Finally, after doing that the function should work. But as I mentioned in the comments, once you have a `List<LineData>`, you can use it directly as a data source for the data grid view - no need to first convert it to a `DataTable`.

Comment: Thanks Ivan for giving me a short lesson on fields and properties. I guess fields have always been so easy to implement in my classes, and they always work as I need them to work, so that is all the further I went. I am now wondering the advantages of properties over fields, if there are any. I will do some research on the subject. Always something new to learn!

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to adding the '{ get; set; }' as you suggested? I realize they are required to get my code in my original question to work.

Comment: @jgayetty No - they are usually inlined, and because of that many people consider exposing public fields to be a bad practice and always use properties. But you already saw one of the drawbacks prior C#6 - auto properties cannot be initialized like fields. Luckily that has been fixed recently. The main advantage is that you control the **setter**.

Comment: @IvanStoev You mentioned to remove property initializers from property definitions for C#<6, but you forgot to remove them ;)

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the extra info regarding any disadvantages. I did learn elsewhere (prompted by your 'lesson') that properties can also be calculated (have code behind them). Pretty cool! I am already dreaming of the possibilities! :-) Thanks to everyone for being kind to C# infants like me!

Answer (score 1):

Although Ivan Stoev answered my question above, here is an alternative solution to my question that I have since discovered (thanks to his help), and am now using. This will return a DataTable comprised of the public 'fields' of the Class in the List. Thought it might help someone in the future. Thanks Ivan!

```
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> data)
    {

        FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(T).GetFields();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
        {
            FieldInfo FI = fields[i];
            table.Columns.Add(FI.Name, FI.FieldType);
        }
        object[] values = new object[fields.Length];
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = fields[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call the method with a `List<object>`, for example, then you will always get an empty result because the `object` type has no properties.

Comment: How do I know if it is a 'List<object>'? I thought everything was an object. My list is of a static class I created.