# Convert Generic Nested List to Datatable

Tags: c#, list, generics, datatable

[Continuation from "Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable)

I've been using the following code to covert a generic `List<T>` into a `DataTable`:

```
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = 
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                 row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

However, I now have a list `List<foo>` where `foo` contains a property `List<bar>` (where `List<bar>` can contain zero values).

**Question:**

I want to convert a generic `List<foo>` containing another generic nested `List<bar>` such as :

```
        List<bar> GenericNestedList = new List<bar>{ new bar("barA"), new bar("barB") };
        List<foo> GenericList = new List<foo> { new foo("fooA", GenericNestedList) };
```

To result in a `DataTable`:

```
| GenericProperty | GenericNestedProperty |
|-----------------|-----------------------|
|      fooA       |         barA          |
|      fooA       |         barB          |
```

The original code accounts for many properties within `foo`, `bar` would also have this requirement.

So far I've been able to retrieve the properties of `bar`, however I've been unable to figure out how to populate the `Datatable` when `List<bar>` is empty. I don't have a lot of experience writing generic methods, so my apologies for not being able to provide a lot of my workings.

**Other Examples:**

*List*

```
List<foo> GenericList = new List<foo> { new foo("fooB", new List<bar>()) };
```

*Datatable*

```
| GenericProperty | GenericNestedProperty |
|-----------------|-----------------------|
|      fooB       |                       |
```

*List*

```
        List<bar> GenericNestedListA = new List<bar>{ new bar("barC"), new bar("barD") };
        List<bar> GenericNestedListB = new List<bar> { new bar("barE"), new bar("barF") };

        List<foo> GenericList = new List<foo> { new foo("fooC", GenericNestedListA),
                                                new foo("fooD", GenericNestedListB) };
```

*Datatable*

```
| GenericProperty | GenericNestedProperty |
|-----------------|-----------------------|
|      fooC       |         barC          |
|      fooC       |         barD          |
|      fooD       |         barE          |
|      fooD       |         barF          |
```

**Classes:**

**foo**

```
class foo
{
    public string GenericProperty;
    public List<bar> GenericNestedList;

    public foo(string GenericProperty, List<bar> GenericNestedList)
    {
        this.GenericProperty = GenericProperty;
        this.GenericNestedList = GenericNestedList;
    }
}
```

**bar**

```
class bar
{
    public string GenericNestedProperty;

    public bar(string GenericNestedProperty)
    {
        this.GenericNestedProperty = GenericNestedProperty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick solution:

```
public DataTable CreateNestedDataTable<TOuter, TInner>(IEnumerable<TOuter> list, string innerListPropertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo[] outerProperties = typeof(TOuter).GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.Name != innerListPropertyName).ToArray();
    PropertyInfo[] innerProperties = typeof(TInner).GetProperties();
    MethodInfo innerListGetter = typeof(TOuter).GetProperty(innerListPropertyName).GetMethod;

    // set up columns
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in outerProperties)
        table.Columns.Add(pi.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType);
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in innerProperties)
        table.Columns.Add(pi.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType);

    // iterate through outer items
    foreach (TOuter outerItem in list)
    {
        var innerList = innerListGetter.Invoke(outerItem, null) as IEnumerable<TInner>;
        if (innerList == null || innerList.Count() == 0)
        {
            // outer item has no inner items
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in outerProperties)
                row[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(outerItem) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        else
        {
            // iterate through inner items
            foreach (object innerItem in innerList)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in outerProperties)
                    row[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(outerItem) ?? DBNull.Value;
                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in innerProperties)
                    row[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(innerItem) ?? DBNull.Value;
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }

    return table;
}
```

One could probably expand this even further, so it could work with multiple nested lists, or automatically recognize the properties that are nested lists. But I kept it simple here.

It’s used like this:

```
var table = CreateNestedDataTable<foo, bar>(GenericList, "GenericNestedList");
```

Tested with your examples, it produces the desired results:

[image: Desired results]

---

Above code uses `PropertyInfo.GetMethod` and `PropertyInfo.GetValue` which were introduced with .NET 4.5. For 4.0, make the following replacements:

```
// before
typeof(TOuter).GetProperty(innerListPropertyName).GetMethod;

// after
typeof(TOuter).GetProperty(innerListPropertyName).GetGetMethod(true);


// for each row assignment
// before
row[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

// after
row[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: Hi @poke, thanks for the response. I'm having two issues with the above code: each `row[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(outerItem) ?? DBNull.Value;` is generating the error "No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments. `typeof(TOuter).GetProperty(innerListPropertyName).GetMethod;` is also generating the error that "'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetMethod'..."

Comment: @Chawin What .NET framework version are you targetting? Both `PropertyInfo.GetValue` and `PropertyInfo.GetMethod` were introduced with .NET 4.5.

Comment: How unusual, I'm running Version 4.5.51209 on Visual C# 2010 express. I'll poke about a bit and see what might be causing the issue.

Comment: @Chawin I’ve added instructions what to replace for older versions. That should make it work.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happened, I certainly didn't mean to! Marked back to accepted :)