# how do I make my DataGridView equal to my List<List<decimal>>?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a List of decimal lists, so when filled it's essentially a grid...

```
2.0, 3.1, 4.0
3.2, 7.0, 1.4
6.0, 3.1, 8.8
```

The code for the List...

```
List<List<decimal>> Rows = new List<List<decimal>>();
```

Is there an easy way to make me DataGridView display this data, I tried...

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = Rows;
```

But this did not work.

the grid outputs like this...
[image]

Comment: What kind of application are you targeting, Windows Forms ? Is there any error that you are getting, what do you mean by did not work.

Comment: @Habib I have edited.

Comment: More questions : Are all your lists in your list of the same size ?

Comment: Looks like you have already specified column names in your grid. Try drag and drop a new grid from the toolbar on your form and then use it for assigning the data source

Comment: Yes each "Row" has the same number of elements.

Comment: @Habib I have not specified column names it seems to be picking them up from the Rows properties somewhere.

Comment: @user3755946, you are right, I just double checked it in a new app

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to convert the list of lists to a [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) object and then set it as the `DataSource` property. Here is an example of a method that does such conversion:

```
public DataTable CreateDataTable(List<List<decimal>> data)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    if (data.Count == 0)
        return table;

    int fields = data[0].Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < fields; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add("column" + (i + 1), typeof (decimal));
    }

    foreach (var list in data)
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < fields; i++)
        {
            row.SetField(i, list[i]);
        }

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return table;
}
```

And then you can set the `DataSource` property like this:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = CreateDataTable(Rows);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing `Capacity` and `Count` is because these are the  properties exposed by `List<T>`, and these properties are used by `GridView` for showing the *values*.

There are multiple ways of doing it, like using a `DataTable` or you can use a LINQ expression to specify column names like:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Rows.Select(d => new
                                {
                                    Col1 = d[0],
                                    Col2 = d[1],
                                    Col3 = d[2]
                                }).ToList();
```

*(You may add a check for column count)*.