# C# Winform (Entity Framework) - cast databound DataGridView or BindingSource to DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, datatable

I am working with C# Winforms and Entity Framework, my project is modeled on this link: [Databinding with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx)

My question is how can I convert a `DataGridView` or a `BindingSource` to a `DataTable`?

I tried this code:

```
DataTable data = (DataTable)(DataGridView1.DataSource);
```

but that failed with an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Then I tried the this code instead:

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)DataGridView1.DataSource;
DataTable dt = (DataTable)bs.DataSource;
```

but this ends up with another error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbLocalView`1[Project1.Contexts.table1]' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Tried to search other similar questions and on other sites but cannot found a way to convert `System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbLocalView` to `DataTable`.

**Edit:**

Here's my code and requirements.

*Requirements:*

I have 2 forms, 1st form has `DataGridView` named `enrollmedsDataGridView` which DataBounded to `enrollmedsBindingSource`. `enrollmedsBindingSource.DataSource` is set to `m3d.enrollmeds.Local` (`m3d` is my context). Window has textbox for the `ItemRemarks`(remarks per item selected), a button for `Save` to save the list and button for `Add` which will open the 2nd form for the selection of items on the Item Masterlist.

To transfer the selected items on the 2nd form to 1st form, I cast the `DataGridView` to `DataTable` then clear the `BindingSource` of 1st form and Re-Add the items selected to `BindingSource`

What I want is to have a way for the 2nd form to know what items are already selected to be able to set the items selected by default (currently 2nd form default is all items are unchecked)

*Codes for 1st Form* `(EnrollMedicationFrm)`:

[image: 1st Form - EnrollMedicationFrm]

```
    M3dEntities m3d = new M3dEntities();
    enrollmeds _enrollmeds;
    EnrollMedSelectionFrm enrollselectfrm;
    public DataTable SelectedItems { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAdmNo { get; set; }

    private void EnrollMedicationFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var _SelectedPKAdm = (from p in m3d.admission
                              where p.admissionNo == SelectedAdmNo
                              select p.PK_Admission).FirstOrDefault();

        int _selectedAdmno = int.Parse(SelectedAdmNo);
        m3d.enrollmeds.Where(adm => adm.FK_Admission == _SelectedPKAdm).ToList();
        this.enrollmedsBindingSource.DataSource = m3d.enrollmeds.Local;
    }


    private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        enrollselectfrm = new EnrollMedSelectionFrm();

        var pxdetails = (from adm in m3d.admission
                        join pxDC in m3d.datacenter
                        on adm.FK_DC_Patient equals pxDC.PK_Datacenter
                        where adm.admissionNo == SelectedAdmNo
                        select new 
                        {
                            adm, 
                            pxDC
                        }).FirstOrDefault();

        if (enrollselectfrm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (SelectedItems == null)
            {
                enrollmedsBindingSource.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                enrollmedsBindingSource.Clear();

                foreach (DataRow dr in SelectedItems.Rows)
                {
                    _enrollmeds = new enrollmeds();

                    _enrollmeds.FK_DC_Patient = pxdetails.pxDC.PK_Datacenter;
                    _enrollmeds.FK_DC_userAdd = mainfrm.PK_DC_UserLoggedIn;
                    var svrDT = ((IObjectContextAdapter)m3d).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<DateTime>("CurrentDateTime() ");
                    DateTime currdatetime = svrDT.AsEnumerable().First();
                    _enrollmeds.AddDateTime = currdatetime;
                    _enrollmeds.FK_Admission = pxdetails.adm.PK_Admission;
                    _enrollmeds.Qty = 0;

                    int pkItems = int.Parse(dr.Field<string>("PK_Items").ToString());
                    var itemdtls = (from i in m3d.items
                                    where i.PK_Items == pkItems
                                    select i).FirstOrDefault();

                    _enrollmeds.FK_Items = pkItems;
                    _enrollmeds.ItemRemarks = itemdtls.ItemRemarks;

                    enrollmedsBindingSource.Add(_enrollmeds);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*Codes for 2nd Form* `(EnrollMedSelectionFrm)`:

[image: 2nd Form - EnrollMedSelectionFrm]

```
    M3dEntities m3d = new M3dEntities();
    private void EnrollMedSelectionFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var items = from i in m3d.items
                    where i.ItemGroup == "Medicine"
                    select new
                    {
                        i.PK_Items,
                        i.ItemID,
                        i.ItemDesc,
                        i.GenericName
                    };

        if (items != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in ItemSelectionDataGridView.Columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(col.Name);
                col.DataPropertyName = col.Name;
            };
            foreach (var element in items)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();
                row["PK_Items"] = element.PK_Items;
                row["ItemID"] = element.ItemID;
                row["ItemDesc"] = element.ItemDesc;
                row["GenericName"] = element.GenericName;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            ItemSelectionDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }

    private void SelectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EnrollMedicationFrm enrollfrm = (EnrollMedicationFrm)Application.OpenForms["EnrollMedicationFrm"];
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)ItemSelectionDataGridView.DataSource;
        DataRow[] result = dt.Select("SelectedChkBox = 1");

        if (result.Count() < 1)
        {
            enrollfrm.SelectedItems = null;
        }
        else
        {
            enrollfrm.SelectedItems = result.CopyToDataTable();
        }

        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

I have many form validations with this flow, but all of them has this issue :(
Once this issue is fixed i think all or most of them can be fixed too

Please guide me on how to solve this problem, other approach or even a workaround could be a great help, Thanks very much in advance :)

Comment: What is the data source type set in the _DataGridView1_?

Comment: Bindingsource of entity framework table1 @Jackdaw

Comment: A `DataGridView` is a **visual** component - much more than just data - so that **cannot** possibly be cast to a `DataTable` (which is **data only**). Same goes for `BindingSource` - this is a non-visual component, but again: it's **much more** than just the bare data, so you cannot just cast it to a `DataTable`. What you need to do is use the **underlying data** for the grid or binding source and cast/convert that to a `DataTable` - or use a `DataTable` to feed the grid or binding source in the first place!

Comment: Hi @marc_s, I think the **underlying data** on my question is the `System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbLocalView`. But I can't find a way to convert `DbLocalView` to `DataTable`. Can you give me a sample or link on how to do the conversion?

Comment: If you have a created `DataTable` in hand then simply add rows to the `DataTable`. If you don't have a `DataTable` and take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/564373/3110834). But I'm curious about the actual requirement which you made think about `DataTable` while using Entity Framewrok.

Comment: Hi @RezaAghaei, please see updated question, I already included the requirements and codes. Please guide me on how to solve my problem or any workaround for this. Thank you very much bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Entity Framework you don't need to use `DataTable`. Instead you should rely on classes like `List<T>`, `DbSet<T>`, `ObservableCollection<T>`, `BindingList<T>` and so on.

Let's focus on current requirement:

> What I want is to have a way for the 2nd form to know what items are
>   already selected...

Consider these notes:

- When you bind a `DataGridView` to a `List<T>`, the `DataBoundItem` property of each row is of type `T`.
- You can search on a `Rows` collection of `DataGridView` by calling [`Cast<DataGridViewRow>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx)

Since you are using a `DataGridView` to check some rows, you can simply have a check-box column in grid and set its name to `CheckBoxColumn1` for example. Then in your select button, you can find checked items this way:

```
private void selectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    var checkedItems = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                            .Where(x => (bool?)x.Cells["CheckBoxColumn1"].Value == true)
                            .Select(x => x.DataBoundItem)
                            .Cast<MyItem>().ToList();

   //use checkedItems 
}
```

In above code I supposed `MyItem` is type of list items which you are showing in grid.

Comment: It seems the answer contains the information which you need to avoid using `DataTable` and keep using typed lists. Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: Hi @RezaAghaei, sorry for late response. Tried your answer by adding some `DataGridView` on the 2nd form, then set the datasource to `checkedItems` and it displays all the items from 1st form only :). The answer solves the problem for the other form to know how what items are selected. However I have another concern, since 1st form has `Qty` and `ItemRemarks` field. I dont know how to implement to remove items (unchecked on 2nd form) on 1st form and retain the edits on Qty and ItemRemarks. Do I need to post this as another question or can it be part of my current question? thanks very much

Comment: Based on my understanding of your question, I think you should not set checked items as data source of your first form, you should somehow use them.

Comment: I don't know what's the usage of those checked item, you know better. For example you can use them to add them to a `List`. You may use them as a filter and ... .  But I can guess using them directly as data source of your first grid probably is not correct. It seems the first grid is showing a `1-N` relation between 2 entities which a leg of this relation is those checked items.

Comment: I just use that to see if it will display all the selected items from other form, but I did use the checkedItems to filter the items, however I don't know how to implement if there is a unchecked items, item must be removed on the other form as well as the Edits on ItemRemarks (must retain) since it is not included on the DataGridView.

Comment: The same way we find the checked items, we can find also un-checked items and use them too. You can return two List<Item>, containing checked and unchecked items and apply whatever you need to do with them.

Comment: I guess, my new concern is not related to my question above. This question is for the 2nd form to know what items are on the 1st form and set the items as checked upon open of 2nd form which already been answered correctly. My new concern is to display the checked items on 2nd form to 1st form, also remove the unchecked items on the 2nd form if item is already in the 1st form before opening of 2nd form, then last is the Edits on the 1st form before open of 2nd form, `Qty` and `ItemRemarks`. `ItemRemarks` is not included on the `DataGridView` but included on binding (see 1st form screen)

Comment: I will tag this question as answered, then will post a separate proper question, for the other viewer not to be confused also. Thank you very much brother @RezaAghaei. Hope you can help me on my future problems. Your a life saver. :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I'll take a look at your new question and will share my idea if I had any idea :)