# C# Winform (Entity Framework) - Iterate thru DBLocal

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I am working with a project modeled on this link: [Databinding with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx)

On the form load on the link, the tutorial set the binding to:

```
        this.categoryBindingSource.DataSource = 
            _context.Categories.Local.ToBindingList();
```

my question is, is it possible to iterate rows and columns on DBlocal? `_context.Categories.Local`? If Yes, how?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes, `Local` property is `ObservableCollection<T>` and you can simply use a `for/foreach` loop.

Comment: But probably it's not your question. What's the problem?

Comment: Hi @RezaAghaei, Can you give me sample on how to do it? I don't have an idea on how to do it on ObservableCollection. Thanks very much brother.. :)

Comment: My problem still connected to my previous question on my 2 forms to display selected items. I do have the details of my question however I can't post it due to I don't know how to implement your answer back to previous form. but I implemented it properly to display the items to item selection form. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DbSet<T>.Local`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248(v=vs.113).aspx) property is `ObservableCollection<T>` and you can simply use a `for/foreach` loop. You can use either of these options:

```
foreach (Category item in context.Category.Local)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(item.Name);      
}
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < context.Category.Local.Count; i++)
{
    var item = context.Category.Local[i];
    //MessageBox.Show(item.Name);
}
```

```
context.Category.Local.ToList()
       .ForEach(item =>
       {
           //MessageBox.Show(item.Name);
       });
```

Don't forget to first load data to `Local`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @RezaAghaei, it's direct to point answer :)

Comment: I'm trying to find whats best approach for my previous problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191624/c-sharp-winform-entity-framework-cast-databound-datagridview-or-bindingsourc), however I find it that I cannot use this approach on my parent concern. since I am working with DataGridView. But since the answer satisfy the question, I will tag this as answered. Thank You Very Much brother. Its a good thing that you always help to others. Thanks again