# Convert IBindingList to DataTable

Tags: c#, binding, dataset, devexpress, fastmember

So I have an `IBindingList` which I have as the data source of a DevExpress chart. It is done this way as the chart updates automatically as the data is gathered.

But instead of creating a separate DataTable and logging the data within that I'd prefer if I could use the `IBindingList` and convert this and the end of the logging to a source that I can bulk insert into a database.

Most methods that I have seen are recursive apart from the FastMember package but I cannot for the life of me convert an `IbindingList` to a `IEnumerable`.

Does anyone have any ideas on this to improve the efficiency of the above?

Comment: Can you show the relevant code? What data storage is behind the IBindingList ?

Comment: I'm confused... [IBindingList inherits IEnumerable.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist(v=vs.110).aspx). By definition any IBindingList is also an IEnumerable....

Comment: Please see this snippet - http://pastebin.com/04d6STb2

It should give you an idea what is going on. I thought as IBindingList inherits IEnumberable I would be able to cast it as an IEnumerable but I couldn't.

This was the FastMember post I referenced when attempting it previously - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=netframework-4.8), IBindingList supports direct conversion to DataTable through extensions methods:

```
CopyToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T>)
```

Returns a DataTable that contains copies of the DataRow objects, given an input IEnumerable object where the generic parameter T is DataRow.

```
CopyToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T>, DataTable, LoadOption)
```

Copies DataRow objects to the specified DataTable, given an input IEnumerable object where the generic parameter T is DataRow.

```
CopyToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T>, DataTable, LoadOption, FillErrorEventHandler)
```

Copies DataRow objects to the specified DataTable, given an input IEnumerable object where the generic parameter T is DataRow.