# How can I convert a List<T> to DataTable with only selected parameters

Tags: c#, list, listview, datatable

I have a `List<Indicators>` where Indicators has several properties.

I have a ListView which holds selected properties of that class as a list of strings.

I want to create a DataTable from the List using only the selected properties in the listview.

So far I can create the columns for the DataTable with the selected parameters in listview. I'm stuck on how to fill each row with data from selected columns only.

the `for` block is where I'm stuck, I know what I have there isn't right. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
  internal DataTable ConvertToDataTableAll(List<Indicators> data)
    {

        DataTable table = new DataTable();           
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listviewFeatures.Items)
        {

            table.Columns.Add(item.Text);

            //this for block should fill the current column with data.
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
            {
                var row = table.NewRow();

                table.Rows.InsertAt(row, i);
                table.Rows[i][item.Text] = data.Select(x => item.Text);

            }

        }
    }
```

Solution with some changes to CodingYoshis suggestion.
This is after adding all columns from code above and removing the for block.

```
        foreach(Indicators ind in data)
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();

            foreach(PropertyInfo prop in ind.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (table.Columns.Contains(prop.Name))
                {
                    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(ind);
                }

            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable

Comment: Why don't you replace your for with:

`foreach(DataRow row in data.Rows)
            {
                row.Text = data.Select(x => item.Text);
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the columns once for the entire table, not for every row as you are doing. So it should be done like this:

```
var firstItem = listviewFeatures.Items.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstItem == null)
{
    // Nothing to convert to datatable so return
    return;
}

// We have items so lets initialize the table
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach (ColumnHeader header in listviewFeatures.Columns)
{
      table.Columns.Add(header);
}

// Now lets add the rows
foreach (ListViewItem item in listviewFeatures.Items)
{

    // Create one row per row in listview
    var row = table.NewRow();

    // Traverse the listview by each column and fill the row
    foreach (ColumnHeader header in listviewFeatures.Columns)
    {
        row[header] = item.Text;
    }

    // Add row to table. It will add it to the end.
    table.Rows.Add(row);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I think that was my problem. However my listviewFeatures.Columns is empty.  I fill listviewFeatures.Items with my selected Parameters from List<Indicators> .  feautres.items contains the column names in string that i want to extract from list<indicators> to datatable.

Comment: Would it be easier to just convert the List<indicators> with all parameters to DataTable then drop the columns I don't want?

Comment: why would that be easier?

Comment: I don't know, my brain just isn't functioning. Appreciate the help, I'll edit my solution.