# c# Nested grid loads multiple times

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I am using telerik radgrid. I am binding the grid programatically. The grid loads correctly but the Nested grid loads multiple times.(the number of times the number of columns in nested grid). Below is my code

```
GridTableView tableViewOrders = new GridTableView(grid);
foreach (Application app in isParentApp)
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable("nestedTable_" + app.AppId);
    objGridList = GetGridList(app.AppId);
    foreach (var nestedRow in objGridList)
    {
       GridRelationFields relationFields = new GridRelationFields();
            relationFields.MasterKeyField = "AppId";
            relationFields.DetailKeyField = "AppId";
            tableViewOrders.ParentTableRelation.Add(relationFields);
            GridBoundColumn boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
            boundColumn.DataField = nestedRow.ColName;
            boundColumn.HeaderText = nestedRow.ColName;
            tableViewOrders.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
            grid.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Add(tableViewOrders);
            tbl.Columns.Add(nestedRow.ColName);
    }
foreach(var rows in totalRows)
 {
        DataRow nestedDtRow = tbl.NewRow();
        nestedDtRow["AppId"] = app.AppId;
    foreach (var nestedRecord in nestedRecords)
    {
        nestedDtRow[nestedRecord.colName] = nestedRecord.Data;
    }
      tbl.Rows.Add(nestedDtRow);
 }
   tableViewOrders.DataSource = tbl;
```

}

While debugging "tbl" had only one table but the output displayed multiple tables.

```
        `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Adding the columns over and over for each row in this loop:

```
foreach (var nestedRow in objGridList)
{
}
```

You only need to do this once outside the loop. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348920/how-can-i-convert-a-listt-to-datatable-with-only-selected-parameters/41349337#41349337) answer on how to do add the columns outside the loop.

Comment: Hi, this loop adds the column only once... the "objGridList" actually has the list of column names.

Comment: When I debug the "tbl" has only one table. But the output displays many tables

Comment: You are adding it once for each row

Comment: But i have closed the loop before I started adding the rows to datatable

Comment: Do you need one column in tbl for each row in objGridList?

Comment: ok I understood what you meant... I am using this grid.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Add(tableViewOrders); inside the loop. It worked fine after moving it outside the loop