# DataGridVew Sorting with Dapper result

Tags: winforms

When I fetch DB result in IEnumerable using Dapper and assign it Datagridview datasource, the Datagridview shows result perfectly but it no more does sorting, resizing, no scrollbars.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Don't think it has anything to do with Dapper !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution myself. Instead of direct assignment of below line of code

```
datagridview.Datasource = data.ToList(); // where data is of type IEnumerable<T>
```

I First converted above "data" to DataTable object, i.e. "dt" and then assigned it to DataGridView.

I used below link to convert IEnumerable data to DataTable.

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable)