# Easy way to fill a DataTable from a List<Model>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am calling into a method that returns a `List<MyViewModel>` and want to fill a `DataTable` from that. I can not change the return type as this method is called in a few others places that need it in that list form. I know I could iterate though the list and fill the table in one row at a time but I was hoping there was more elegant solution like it's `.Load` function for `iDataReader`.

Comment: Just curious - why you want convert light and readable `List<MyViewModel>` to the complicated `DataTable` object?

Comment: A plugin I use to export information to Excel requires the incoming data to be in a DataTable.

Comment: Any solution will loop collection - so I think classic loop with adding row for every item in the list will be simple enough approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable)

Comment: @Matthew are you absolutely certain? EPPlus can export both DataTable with `LoadFromDataTable` and strongly-typed collections with `LoadFromCollection`. If your library can't handle lists, switch to EPPlus

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/564373/894792

Comment: @Fabio you are right this is a dup of that. In my searching I did not run across it.

Comment: You really should avoid DataTable in favor of strongly typed models as much as you can.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks I will look into EPPlus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments it seems the *real* problem is that you want to export a strongly typed list to an Excel file but the library you use only accepts a DataTable.

I'd suggest you use the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample) library instead, which can load data both from a DataTable and collections, eg:

```
sheet.LoadFromDataTable(myTable);
```

or

```
sheet.LoadFromCollection(myList);
```

EPPlus is available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) too.

In general, you can easily convert a collection to a DataTable with [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq)'s [ToDataTable()](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#todatatable) extension, eg:

```
var myTable=myList.ToDataTable();
```

You can find the extension's code [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ToDataTable.cs). MoreLINQ is available as [a NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq) as well.

Comment: Thank you, you are right in my intent and I will look at EPPLus. I will also look into the link to examine it more just as a learning thing.

Comment: MoreLINQ is open source. You can find the source for ToDataTable [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ToDataTable.cs)

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataTable TableFromMyViewModel(params MyViewModel[] items)
{
    DataTable _result = new DataTable("MyViewModel");

    // Do this for each field
    _result.Columns.Add("Field1", typeof(String));
    _result.Columns.Add("Field2", typeof(int));
    _result.Columns.Add("Field3", typeof(String));

    foreach (MyViewModel _item in items)
    {
        DataRow _row = _result.NewRow();
        _row["Field1"] = _item.Field1;
        _row["Field2"] = _item.Field2;
        _row["Field3"] = _item.Field3;
        _result.Rows.Add(_row);
    }

    return _result;
}
```