# Petapoco with Datatable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, petapoco

I am new in Petapoco,Can I retrieve table data as Datatable using stored procedure in petapoco ORM ? I tried in google but I didn't get any answer from google.Any one know that?

Comment: you can use sql statement like "exec sp_name @@param1 = @0" and give your parameters

Comment: You can do this, but note that the idea of PetaPoco is to give you strongly typed objects to work with; if you want a DataTable, you can use standard ADO.NET methods to do so.

Answer (score 1):

step 1:

```
    public DataTable ListToDataTable(IList list)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        if (list.Count <= 0) return dt;

        var properties = list[0].GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var pi in properties)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType);
        }

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            properties.ToList().ForEach(p => row[p.Name] = p.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value);
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

step 2:

```
    var list = db.Fetch<dynamic>(sql);
    var dt = ListToDataTable(list);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But the same code is not working for me.I created some changes in your code.Then Its working fine.The below is the changes.

Comment: var dt = new DataTable();
            if (list.Count <= 0) return dt;
            var obj = list[0];
            var eoAsDict = ((IDictionary<String, Object>)obj);           
            eoAsDict.ToList().ForEach(p => dt.Columns.Add(p.Key));
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var eoAsDict1 = ((IDictionary<String, Object>)item);
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                eoAsDict1.ToList().ForEach(p => row[p.Key] = p.Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return dt;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can execute stored procedures using Petapoco.

Example:

```
var result = db.Fetch<dynamic>(";EXEC GetSomething @@Year = @0", 2017);
```

Petapoco returns a `List<T>` and I recommend you to use List instead of  Datatable, but if you want you can [convert your list to a Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable)