# System.NotSupportedException: ''DataSet' supports not System.Nullable<>

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am retrieving `propertyInfos` from a given type.

When a property is of type `Nullable<int>` then I can not add the property type to the `dataTable.columns` collection because I get an exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: ''DataSet' supports not
>   System.Nullable<>.'

```
foreach (var prop in propertyInfos)
{
    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int?))
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }
    else
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);

    }
}
```

What should I change in the if-clause to make it work?

I already added `null` or `DBNull` to the collection but that did not help?!

Comment: Did you just try int? int is also a type. You can debug and look which types you are getting while iterating your properties. So you can recognize to which type you have to compare against. When your property is from Nullable<int> you can check for typeof(int?) and then get the underlying type via `Type yourIntType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType);`

Comment: [Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805044/3110834)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) and [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx) method for this purpose:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(
                              prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
```

Comment: Not quite there, you also need to set the column to be nullable.

Comment: No, I mean `var column = dataTable.Columns.Add(...); column.AllowDBNull = true;`(or `false` of course)

Comment: @DavidG The default it true for [`AllowDBNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.allowdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx).