# extract list of string from list of complex type

Tags: c#

How can I obtain from `List<ComplexObject>` a `List<string>`, supposing ComplexObject has two properties: prop1 of type string and prop2 of type int. And I am interested to extract a `List<string>` (list of prop1).

With an example, maybe it's clearer.

Imagine you have `List<Country>` where Country is the complex object with Id and Name. And I am interested to extract from countryList just a nameList with all the names.

I know I can do something like:

```
            List<string> nameList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var country in countryList)
            {
                nameList.Add(country.Name);
            }
```

...but I am wondering if there is a simpler and quicker way to extract nameList from countryList. Maybe with lambda or something.

And also can that list of strings be easily then converted into a `DataTable`?

Thank you.

Comment: depends .. what are you doing with the DataTable? There might be an easier way without DataTable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a common use case for a LINQ select that converts the result enumeration into a list. It's easier done than said:

```
var nameList = countryList.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

Conversion to a DataTable doesn't come so conveniently packaged. [Here's an answer about doing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/564373/424129) that.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ:

```
var names = countryList.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
```