# How To Convert 'system.collections.generic.list ' to 'system.data.datatable'

Tags: c#

Here i am trying to bind the user list `uow.Repository<User>().GetAll().ToList();` to `DataTable dt` but there is a error saying cannot convert type 'system.collections.generic.list ' to 'system.data.datatable' in line `dt = uow.Repository<User>().GetAll().ToList();`.
Below is my code

```
 public DataTable GetAllUser1()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = uow.Repository<User>().GetAll().ToList();
        return dt;
    }
```

Any Help will be highy appreciated.Thank you

Comment: You need to construct table using User's properties and then insert  rows for every user object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following method to convert List to DataTable

```
public DataTable GetAllUser1()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ToDataTable(uow.Repository<User>().GetAll().ToList());
    return dt;
}


public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
    //Get all the properties
    PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
    {
        //Setting column names as Property names
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
    }
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        var values = new object[Props.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
        {
            //inserting property values to datatable rows
            values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);

        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
    return dataTable;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without much code and mess use [Linq to data set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = uow.Repository<User>().GetAll().AsEnumerable();

DataTable dt = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

> The CopyToDataTable method uses the following process to create a
>   DataTable from a query:
>
> 1.The CopyToDataTable method clones a DataTable from the source table (a DataTable object that implements the IQueryable interface). The
>   IEnumerable source has generally originated from a LINQ to DataSet
>   expression or method query.
>
> 2.The schema of the cloned DataTable is built from the columns of the first enumerated DataRow object in the source table and the name of
>   the cloned table is the name of the source table with the word "query"
>   appended to it.
>
> 3.For each row in the source table, the content of the row is copied into a new DataRow object, which is then inserted into the cloned
>   table. The RowState and RowError properties are preserved across the
>   copy operation. An ArgumentException is thrown if the DataRow objects
>   in the source are from different tables.
>
> 4.The cloned DataTable is returned after all DataRow objects in the input queryable table have been copied. If the source sequence does
>   not contain any DataRow objects, the method returns an empty
>   DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [`method`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable) to convert list to **`DataTable`**

```
public DataTable GetAllUser1()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt =ToDataTable(uow.Repository<User>().GetAll().ToList());
    return dt;
}

public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = 
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
             row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = uow.Repository<User>().GetAll().ToList();
```

It doesn't work like that. You should use the `DataTable` methods to fill it. Providing an example would provide better understanding. For example; the `User` class contains these properties;

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You should specify the columns for `DataTable`;

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
```

Now, you can add rows in a simple loop;

```
    var userList = uow.Repository<User>().GetAll().ToList();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    foreach (var user in userList)
    {
        var newRow = dt.NewRow();
        newRow["Id"] = user.Id;
        newRow["Name"] = user.Name;
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
```

Also, you can provide a solution dynamically by getting the properties and accessing them using `Reflection`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly convert list to Data Table

instead you can build up a generic function. mentioned in below code. You need to convert your list to build up Data Table Rows and Columns.

```
public DataTable ConvertTODataTable<T>(IList<T> data)// T is any generic type
{         
 PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
        }
        object[] values = new object[props.Count];
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return table;
    }
```