# Copy the Contents of DataGrid in Wpf to DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one dataGrid filled with some values.

I need to copy the contents of dataGrid to dataTable.

After copying the DataTable to Excel sheet, the result was not the expected one. Kinly help in fixing this. The below was the result.[image: Here is the result]

```
     private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add();
        }

        System.Data.DataRow dr;
        for (int row = 0; row < dataGrid.Items.Count; row++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                dr[col] = dataGrid.Items[col];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }

         //dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
         //dt = (System.Data.DataTable)dataGrid.ItemsSource;
    }
```

Comment: and how do you export to excel ? a simple break point at 
    dr[col] = dataGrid.Items[col]; should tell you what is the value being saved in dr[col]

Comment: @Muds, The value mentioned in the excel was the value stored in dr[col].

Comment: easiest would be to read from the bound object and converting it to a DT

are you binding any collection to data grid

Comment: @Muds, yes I'm binding the ObservableCollection

Comment: great. then just convert that observable collection to data table

Comment: @Muds, I need the data only from dataGrid. The user need to have the facility of modifying the values at the runtime. Only the final data should be pushed to dataTable from dataGrid.

Comment: when user makes changes, the changes are propagated to collection

Comment: What kind of ObservableCollection are you binding to? And are you using auto-generated columns? Please post your XAML.

Answer (score 0):

instead of reading from data grid read it from the bound collection

```
var table = new DataTable();
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data)) 
{
    table.Load(reader);
}
```

and there you have a data table, for further details you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/564373/4303098)

Comment: data is your bound collection

Comment: I don't have that ObjectReader function. I'm unable to access the FastMember.

Comment: there is a nuget package called FastMember, also look at this git link..

https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member