# Export to Excel in ASP.Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core-2.0

I used to export data to excel in asp.net mvc using below code

```
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportedHtml.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    this.EnableViewState = false;
    Response.Write(ExportDiv.InnerHtml);
    Response.End();
```

When this Code Run it create a file and ask for a location to save

I tried working with NPOI and create Excel file very well but cant save file on client location .

Is there any way to make above code works on asp.net core 2.0 or any other way where I can save data in excel format on client machine ?

Comment: Websites cannot unilaterally save files to visitor's disks.

Comment: Ok , than what we call this behaviour for asp.net , they do save

Comment: I used another library called EPPlus (https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) to generate Excel files and turn them into binary before sending back to the client. In .Net Core (or Mvc in general), you can return File() from controller actions.

Comment: I can but it needs to be tomorrow as I am going to bed soon. In the meanwhile, you can check out the sample the library has: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/tree/master/SampleWebApp.Core.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that.

### Option 1: save to wwwroot

You can generate the Excel and save it to the `wwwroot` folder. And then you can serve it as static content on the page.

For example you have a folder called 'temp' inside the `wwwroot` folder to contain all the newly generated excels.

```
<a href="\temp\development\user1\2018\5\9\excel1.xlsx" download>Download</a>
```

There are limitations on this approach. 1 of them is the new `download` attribute. It only works on modern browsers.

### Option 2: byte array

Another way is to generate the Excel, convert it into byte array and send it back to the controller. For that I use a library called "EPPlus" (v: 4.5.1) which supports .Net Core 2.0.

The following is just some sample codes I put together to give you an idea. It's not production ready.

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;

namespace DL.SO.Web.UI.Controllers
{
    public class ExcelController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Download()
        {
            byte[] fileContents;

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

                // Put whatever you want here in the sheet
                // For example, for cell on row1 col1
                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Long text";

                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Font.Size = 12;
                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;

                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Hair;

                // So many things you can try but you got the idea.

                // Finally when you're done, export it to byte array.
                fileContents = package.GetAsByteArray();
            }

            if (fileContents == null || fileContents.Length == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return File(
                fileContents: fileContents,
                contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                fileDownloadName: "test.xlsx"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I got the idea , I am able to do this by breaking the whole process in two step . Step 1 is saving the excel file in wwwroot folder using NPOI and second step is using return File() statement to save it on client machine . Its work very well , Problem Solved .

Comment: Hi, the second one is a good approach, but how I download the file then in the frontend??

Comment: @YuriMorales: Generate a url to call the `Download()` action in the `ExcelController`? For example, `Url.Action("download", "excel", new { area = "" })`?

Comment: No, sorry forgot to mention is VueJs frontend, my backend is net core webapi, but I already solved the prolem with npm package file-saver.

Comment: no, do not allow people to generate XML and serve the content as static content from `wwwroot`! are you kidding!?

Comment: @ChaimEliyah: I am not saying it's the best option, but it is a working option. From my experience, sometimes due to company policy, you can't always save the files as bytes in database.

Comment: I understand. But I'd write a nice validator around it to make sure you are only serving files uploaded by an authenticated human user, and that they don't contain standard attack patterns.

Answer (score 5):

Agreed with David Liang's answer.

**Slide modifications if want to export whole DataTable.**

```
            string export="export";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //Fill datatable
            dt = *something*

            byte[] fileContents;
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(export);
                worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
                fileContents = package.GetAsByteArray();
            }
            if (fileContents == null || fileContents.Length == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return File(
                fileContents: fileContents,
                contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                fileDownloadName: export + ".xlsx"
            );
```

Comment: for people who wants to convert the List to Datatable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable

Answer (score 1):

Here is our solution to this:

[image: Depends on EPPlus.Core/1.5.4]

```
using OfficeOpenXml;

public class XmlService
{
    // [...]
    public void getXlsxFile(SomeTableObject tbl, ref byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(tbl.name);
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);
            bytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();
        }
    }
}
```

More information on EPPlus is available [here](https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core) and the source code above can be found at [our open source repo (GPL)](https://github.com/SavageLearning/Machete/blob/develop/Machete.Service/ReportsV2Service.cs#L93).

Comment: Side note:this package is unfortunately deprecated.

Comment: If you scroll down to the README, the deprecated package directs users to use the original EPPlus, which now supports Core++/MVC 5. I am swamped currently, but will update the answer when I can for archival purposes.

Comment: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/tree/master/SampleWebApp.Core

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code instead of your own:

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = "attachment; filename=ExportedHtml.xls";
    Response.WriteAsync(sb.ToString()).Wait();
```