# (NugetPackage) AdvancedDataGridView Sorting/Filtering a list

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

To give an introduction, I have an datagridview now that is filled with data from an list.

I wanted to make the ordering and filtering easier for the user so I started using [ADGV](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ADGV/).

It uses the type of ordering and filtering like Excel does it. Now they have made all the methods, but the actual ordering/filtering is something you need to do yourself.

I have followed some tutorials and there they are not really using List as a datasource. In the [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaZeeHRRCGA) they use the Sort and Filter method, and List does not accept like the way they do it in the tutorials.

**Is there a way to Sort/Filter a linq list with a sortstring/filterstring like they do it in the video [here (4:45)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaZeeHRRCGA).**

Comment: I would always try first to go with a [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx) as DataSource and its sort and filtering capabilities.

Comment: @TaW Why may I ask?

Comment: Because I like the sortstring/filterstring method, which is what you are looking for, too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an alternative answer that has worked for me.

While the above answer is great and works, because you are copying all the data out of the list, if you do this, you lose the benefits of data binding.

For example, if the list changes somewhere else in the app, or the user edits any of the data in the grid, the changes aren't reflected back.  This is the problem I was having.

So, another potential solution is to use dynamic linq and filter the list of objects yourself in the `FilterStringChanged` event handler. I wrote a solution for this which can be found here:

https://github.com/davidegironi/advanceddatagridview/issues/24

Its just another option for people out there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a built-in way to support sorting and filtering a `List<T>` using the `FilterString` and `SortString` generated by the `AdvancedDataGridView`, the answer is: No, there is not a built-in way. The filter is generated in `ADGVFilterMenu` and as far as I see, there is no way to override the filter generation.

But you can convert your `List<T>` to a `DataTable` and sort and filter simply using those strings. For example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = db.Products.ToList();
    this.productBindingSource.DataSource = list.ToDataTable(); 
}
private void advancedDataGridView1_SortStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.productBindingSource.Sort = advancedDataGridView1.SortString;
}
private void advancedDataGridView1_FilterStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.productBindingSource.Filter = advancedDataGridView1.FilterString;
}
```

In above example, I've used the `ToDataTable` extension method from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805044/3110834):

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, 
                Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void advancedDataGridView1_SortStringChanged(object sender, Zuby.ADGV.AdvancedDataGridView.SortEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SortString.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        string[] strtok = e.SortString.Split(',');
        foreach (string str in strtok)
        {
            string[] columnorder = str.Split(']');
            ListSortDirection lds = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            if (columnorder[1].Trim().Equals("DESC"))
            {
                lds = ListSortDirection.Descending;
            }
            advancedDataGridView1.Sort(advancedDataGridView1.Columns[columnorder[0].Replace('[', ' ').Trim()], lds);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add details on the answer. Avoid giving only code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void advancedDataGridView1_FilterStringChanged(object sender, Zuby.ADGV.AdvancedDataGridView.FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = MyTable.Select(advancedDataGridView1.FilterString).CopyToDataTable();
    }
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, it would be more helpful if you shortly explain your code.

Comment: To add to @KlausGütter 's comment It also makes the site more useful for people (of various levels of experience) who might come across the question later.