# Create datatable from a variable that used LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I am new to LINQ and am trying to create a collection say "DBDatalog" of only one column DCID and then converting that collection to datatable.

```
 var DBDatalog = from records in this.Points
                                          where records.UsesLegacyStorage == false
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              DcId = records.DCId,
                                          };
```

I want to be able to do something like this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("DCId", typeof(Int32));
```

AND for the contents of DataTable

```
DataTable dataTable = DBDatalog.toDataTable();
```

But that is not working. How can I convert my collection set attained in the dbdatalog to convert to data table.

Points is a list of objects defined like this
public List Points = new List();
and Exports is defined like this.

```
public class ExportPoint
    {
        public int DCID;
        public int BuildingId;
        public string BuildingName;
}
```

Comment: What is in records? What is in DBDatalog? Also please give a better problem decription then "not working".

Comment: @Christopher, thanks much By not working I mean, toDataTable is not defined. I need a way to convert DBDataLog to DataTable.  DBDatalog is defined as a var in code above.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable

Comment: @Sarah: IIRC, LINQ uses a Enumeartor. Or rather the result is a Enumerator. You can just ittearte it over in a foreach loop and add something similar to each element to the DataTable.

Comment: DataTable dataTable = DBDatalog.AsEmumerable().CopyToDataTable();

Comment: @Harsh, I looked up that link and didnt help me much. Like I said I am new to Linq and collections and that link on stackoverflow was not much helpful.

Comment: @jdweng trying that. Will let you know soon.

Comment: @jdweng this is the error I am getting when I follow your suggestion.. 'IEnumerable<<>f__AnonymousType0<int>>' does not contain a definition for 'AsEmumerable' and no accessible extension method 'AsEmumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<<>f__AnonymousType0<int>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `foreach (var a in DBDatalog) dt.Rows.Add(a.DcId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for hours for an answer which is most uncomplicated and straight forward. This is what I found, I am placing it here in case it helps someone else.

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DBDatalog);
```

The above line will give you a string like this 
`"[{\"DcId\":755},{\"DcId\":7482},{\"DcId\":490}]"`

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
```

This works like a charm, no need to write extension methods and all that stuff.

Thanks to this answer very clean and to the point. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34202937/7817343