# Processing and Filtering of osm-File(osm.pbf) is taking way too long in C#

Tags: c#, .net, openstreetmap, large-data, large-files

**Scenario:** I want to write my own Autocomplete-API for Addresses, just like the One Google is offering. (Very Basic: Street, Housenumber, City, Postcode, Country). It is intended for private use and training-purposes only. I want to cover about 1 Million Addresses for a Start.

**Technology Used:** .Net Framework (not Core), C#, Visual Studio, OSMSharp, Microsoft SQL-Server, Web Api 2 (although i will probably switch to ASP.Net Core in the Future.)

**Approach:**

- Set Up Project (Web Api 2 or Console Project for Demo-Purposes)
- Download relevant File from OpenStreetMaps using DownloadClient() (https://download.geofabrik.de/)
- Read in the File using OSMSharp and Filter out relevant Data.
- Convert Filtered Data to a DataTable.
- Use DataTable to feed SQLBulkCopy Method to import Data into Database.

**Problem:** Step 4 is taking way too long. For a File like "Regierungsbezirk Köln" in the Format osm.pbf which is about 160MB (the uncompressed osm file is about 2.8 GB) where talking about 4-5 Hours. I want to optimize this. The Bulk Copy of the DataTable into the Database on the other Hand (About 1 Million Rows) is taking just about 5 Seconds. (Woah. Amazing.)

**Minimal Reproduction:** https://github.com/Cr3pit0/OSM2Database-Minimal-Reproduction

**What i tried:**

- Use a Stored Procedure in SQL-Server. This comes with a whole different Set of Problems and i didn't quite manage to get it Working (mainly because the uncompressed osm.pbf File is over 2GB and SQL Server doesn't like that)
- Come up with a different approach to Filter and Convert the Data from the File to a DataTable (or CSV).
- Use the Overpass-API. Although I read somewhere that the Overpass-API is not intended for DataSets above 10,000 Entries.
- Ask the Jedi-Grandmasters on StackOverflow for Help. (Currently in Process ... :D)

**Code Extract:**

```cs
public static DataTable getDataTable_fromOSMFile(string FileDownloadPath)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Finished Downloading. Reading File into Stream...");

    using (var fileStream = new FileInfo(FileDownloadPath).OpenRead())
    {
        PBFOsmStreamSource source = new PBFOsmStreamSource(fileStream);

        if (source.Any() == false)
        {
            return new DataTable();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished Reading File into Stream. Filtering and Formatting RawData to Addresses...");
        Console.WriteLine();

        DataTable dataTable = convertAdressList_toDataTable(
                    source.Where(x => x.Type == OsmGeoType.Way && x.Tags.Count > 0 && x.Tags.ContainsKey("addr:street"))
                    .Select(Address.fromOSMGeo)
                    .Distinct(new AddressComparer())
                );

        return dataTable;
    }
};
```

```cs
private static DataTable convertAdressList_toDataTable(IEnumerable<Address> addresses)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    if (addresses.Any() == false)
    {
        return dataTable;
    }

    dataTable.Columns.Add("Id");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Street");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Housenumber");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("City");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Postcode");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Country");

    Int32 counter = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Finished Filtering and Formatting. Writing Addresses From Stream to a DataTable Class for the Database-SQLBulkCopy-Process ");

    foreach (Address address in addresses)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(counter + 1, address.Street, address.Housenumber, address.City, address.Postcode, address.Country);
        counter++;

        if (counter % 10000 == 0 && counter != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrote " + counter + " Rows From Stream to DataTable.");
        }
    }

    return dataTable;
};
```

Comment: Did you already try to use a profiler in order to determine your bottleneck(s)?

Comment: You'd need to show us your code for how you generate your `DataTable`, as that is where your bottle neck is. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/564373/3181

Comment: All of the Relevant Code is in the Project of github. I dont know if its appreciated if i just copy and paste dozens of lines of code into this Question. As for the Bottleneck. I used simple Logs which include DateTimes to determine which Operation is taking the longest.

Comment: @StuartGrassie FastMember sounds interesting, although i'm not sure if that is what i need. I will check it out when i have the Time.

Comment: As @StuartGrassie says, your `DataTable` populating code is **hideously** inefficient as you're populating row-by-row. FastMember or similar is your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i think i got it. Im down to about 12 Minutes for a File-Size of about 600mb and about 3.1 Million Rows of Data after Filtering.

The first Thing i tried is to replace the logic that populates my DataTable with FastMember. Which worked, but didnt give the Performance Increase i was hoping for (I canceled the Process after 3 Hours...). After more Research i stumbled upon an old Project which is called "osm2mssql" (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=osm2mssql). I used a little part of the Code which directly read the Data from the osm.pbf File and modified it to my Use-Case ( → which is to extract Address-Data from Ways). I did actually use FastMember to write an `IEnumerable<Address>` to the Datatable, but i dont need OSM-Sharp and whatever extra Dependencies they have anymore. So thank you very much for the Suggestion of FastMember. I will certainly keep that Library in Mind in future Projects.

For those who are interested, i updated my Github-Project accordingly (https://github.com/Cr3pit0/OSM2Database-Minimal-Reproduction) (although i didnt thoroughly test it, because i moved on from the Test-Project to the Real Deal, which is a Web Api)

Im quite sure it can be further optimized but i dont think i care at the Moment. 12 Minutes for a Method which might be called once a month to update the whole Database is fine i guess. Now i can move on to opimizing my Queries for the Autocomplete.

So thank you very much to whoever wrote "osm2mssql".