# How-to convert a dictionary to a datatable?

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

Using C#, how-to convert a dictionary to a datatable?

There is an example on how-to convert a list into a datatable at
[Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable)

I started working on this, since 2019-12-17.

And, I have searched, Google, Stackoverflow, and Microsoft websites.

```
public static DataTable DictionaryToDataTable<T>(this IDictionary<K, V> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection propertiesK = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(K));
    PropertyDescriptorCollection propertiesV = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(V));

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in propertiesK)
       table.Columns.Add(prop.Name,
                         Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType)
                         ?? prop.PropertyType);

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in propertiesV)
        table.Columns.Add
              (prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType)  
                          ?? prop.PropertyType);

    foreach(KeyValuePair<K, V> item in data)
    {
       DataRow row = table.NewRow();

       foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in propertiesK)
          row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

       foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in propertiesV)
          row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

       table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return table;
}
```

```
Type ex = typeof(InformationInTransit.ProcessLogic.DataTableHelper);
MethodInfo mi = ex.GetMethod("DictionaryToDataTable");
MethodInfo miConstructed = 
   mi.MakeGenericMethod
   (
      typeof
      (
          Dictionary
          <
              String,
              InformationInTransit.ProcessLogic.Exact.Participation
          >
      )
   );

   object[] args = {result};
   DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) miConstructed.Invoke
   (
       null,
       args
   );
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your code.

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

one attempt would simply be something like this:

```
        Dictionary<int,int> dictionary=new Dictionary<int, int>();
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Val", typeof(int));

        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Key"] = item.Key;
            dr["Val"] = item.Value;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

once try this: (nameList and globalVariable are list)

```
            var dictionary = nameList.Zip(globalVariable, (k, v) => new { Key = k, Value = v })
                                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Variable names", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Variable values", typeof(string));

                foreach (var pair in dictionary)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Variable names"] = pair.Key;
                    dr["Variable values"] = pair.Value;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it more convenient to write this as a generic for a Dictionary of any types.  As a further refinement, you can make it as an Extension Method.  Something like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> data, string colName1, string colName2)
    {

        var dT = new DataTable();
        dT.Columns.Add(colName1, typeof(TKey));
        dT.Columns.Add(colName2, typeof(TValue));

        foreach (var kVP in data)
        {
            var nR = dT.NewRow();
            nR[0] = kVP.Key;
            nR[1] = kVP.Value;
            dT.Rows.Add(nR);
        }

        return dT;
    }

}
```

It can be called simply by

```
var dT = myDictionary.ConvertToDataTable("keyColumnName", "valueColumnName");
```