# Linq Query to Dataset

Tags: linq-to-sql

I got a linq query. I wanna take this query results to a dataset. How can I do this ?

```
var variable = from t in db.Islems
               where t.Tarih >= dateTimePicker1.Value
                     && t.Tarih < dateTimePicker2.Value
               select t;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

I wanna load the query results to the dataset, then use it in Crystal Reports.

Comment: crystal reports doesn't support generic collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the extension method that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523153/how-do-i-transform-a-listt-into-a-dataset/523168#523168), it uses reflection and generics to convert any IEnumerable<T> collection to a DataTable.