# list to dataset using C#

Tags: c#, .net

How to convert list to dataset using c#?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1245662/108847

Comment: Why negative.. good question??

Comment: @AmRan, I'm not a downvoter but this is duplicated, Also OP doesn't say what try before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//
// Conventional way
//
private DataSet GetDataSetConventional(List<FileSearchResultItem> list)
{
    DataSet _result = new DataSet();
    _result.Tables.Add("results");
    _result.Tables("results").Columns.Add("A");
    _result.Tables("results").Columns.Add("B");
    _result.Tables("results").Columns.Add("C");
    _result.Tables("results").Columns.Add("D");
    _result.Tables("results").Columns.Add("E");
    _result.Tables("results").Columns.Add("F");
    _result.Tables("results").Columns.Add("G");

    foreach (FileSearchResultItem item in list) {
        DataRow newRow = _result.Tables("results").NewRow();
        newRow("A") = item.Index;
        newRow("B") = item.Image;
        newRow("C") = item.Name;
        newRow("D") = item.Size;
        newRow("E") = item.Files;
        newRow("F") = item.IsDirectory;
        _result.Tables("results").Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
    return _result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/4779575f-c268-4471-a980-dc4dc1d91a45/)

You basically use a for loop to go through the list and map the list items to DataTable items creating a new row each iteration.