# Nullable types in Crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, nullable

I am using asp.net mvc and crystal reports v.13.

i have two class which contains nullable variables.

```
public class CustomerList
{
    public List<customerinfo> custInfo{ get; set; }
}
public class customerinfo
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> age{ get; set; }
}
```

A list of objects of above class (CustomerList) is set in  data source of crystal report.

```
rd.SetDataSource(rptSource);
```

In crystal reports i am selecting the same class  from database expert using .net Objects.

Since i am using nullable variable i am getting the following error:

> "DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your generic list to a DataSet and set it as DataSource of the report

below answer will help you to do the conversion

[Convert generic list to dataset in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245662/convert-generic-list-to-dataset-in-c-sharp/3719280#3719280)

Comment: so according to your opinion what will be the solution?

Comment: I don't know about solution, I just want to point; you just write a reference to another answer. You didn't add any personal information and I think this could be better as a comment. As I said, these are just my opinions.. If you think this is a real answer, keep it `;)`

Comment: @SonerGönül have you read my answer? is it just pointing another answer?

Comment: You just add _You can convert your generic list to a DataSet and set it as DataSource of the report_ line. If you remove this line, answer doesn't loose anything. But anyway..

Comment: @SonerGönül **If you remove this line, answer doesn't loose anything** what? read the question again, and check the linked answer and my answer. I know what is the different between comment and answer.