# Decompressing GZip Stream from HTTPClient Response

Tags: c#, json, wcf, gzip

I am trying to connect to an api, that returns GZip encoded JSON, from a WCF service (WCF service to WCF service). I am using the **HTTPClient** to connect to the API and have been able to return the JSON object as a string. However I need to be able to store this returned data in a database and as such I figured the best way would be to return and store the JSON object in an array or byte or something along those lines.

What I am having trouble with specifically is the decompressing of the GZip encoding and have been trying lots of different example but still cant get it.

The below code is how I am establishing my connection and getting a response, this is the code that returns a string from the API.

```
public string getData(string foo)
{
    string url = "";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    string responseJsonContent;
    try
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        response = client.GetAsync(url + foo).Result;
        responseJsonContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return responseJsonContent;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return "";
    }
}
```

I have been following a few different examples like these [StackExchange API](https://web.archive.org/web/20150312130407/http://cgeers.com/2011/10/02/stack-exchange-api/), [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and a couple on stackoverflow, but I haven't been able to get any of these to work for me.

What is the best way to accomplish this, am I even on the right track?

Thanks guys.

Comment: "the best way would be to return and store the JSON object in an array or byte" Note that a string is an array of bytes.

Answer (score 322, accepted):

Just instantiate HttpClient like this:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler)) //see update below
{
    // your code
}
```

***Update June 19, 2020:***
It's not recommended to use  httpclient in a 'using' block as it might cause port exhaustion.

```
private static HttpClient client = null;
    
ContructorMethod()
{
   if(client == null)
   {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        };        
        client = new HttpClient(handler);
   }
// your code            
 }
```

If using .Net Core 2.1+, consider using [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) and injecting like this in your startup code.

```
 var timeout = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

 services.AddHttpClient<XApiClient>().ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        }).AddPolicyHandler(request => timeout);
```

Comment: If I use this structure, how do I retrieve the content of my response from the httpClient?  I'm super new to c# and I don't think I'm getting it.

Comment: @FoxDeploy there is no change needed for the code to get the content when you use this solution. See here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597665/how-to-get-content-body-from-a-httpclient-call

Comment: even though it is an old post, this answer just solved my problem in .netcore, moving from 1.1 to 2.0 it seems the client was automatically doing the decompression, so I had to add this code in 2.0 to make it work... Thanks!

Comment: Just to piggy back on @SebastianCastaldi, but .net core 1.1 had AutomaticDecompression set properly, but in .net core 2.0 it is set to NONE.  This took me way too long to figure out...

Comment: Is HttpClient unable to decompress `Brotli`? It seems that `DecompressionMethods`'s only options are `None`, `GZip`, and `Deflate`.

Comment: Note: `HttpClient` Should NOT be used inside `using`

Comment: I am using it on Xamarin iOS widget and it is crashed. But I don't know why. Could you give me some suggestion @DIG

Comment: I second @imba-tjd to never use using with HttpClient.  You will cause port exhaustion with any real traffic.  You should only instantiate HttpClient once during app lifetime if possible.

Comment: np!  I learned the hard way when every VM on a host in our cluster stopped working complaining about ports.  It took weeks to figure out it was an app that wasn't using HttpClient correctly.

Comment: I must put an emphasis on the upvoted comment [`HttpClient` should NOT be used inside a `using` block](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: For .NET 5 (not sure about 3) it must be configured like this... (because TimeOut is no longer a policy)
services.AddHttpClient<ApiClient>(client => 
 client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( webOptions.HttpTimeout))
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
    {
     AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Brotli
    } );

Comment: Blazor does not support AutomaticDecompression you will get the error System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.

Answer (score 5):

I used code from below link to decompress GZip stream.Then used the decompressed byte array to get the required JSON object. Hope it may help some one.

```
var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
var decompressedData = Decompress(readTask);
string jsonString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedData, 0, decompressedData.Length);
ResponseObjectClass responseObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObjectClass>(jsonString);
```

https://www.dotnetperls.com/decompress

```
static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzip)
{
    using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzip), CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        const int size = 4096;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0);
            return memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I eventually solved my problem. If there are better ways please let me know :-)

```
        public DataSet getData(string strFoo)
    {
        string url = "foo";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response;   
        DataSet dsTable = new DataSet();
        try
        {
               //Gets the headers that should be sent with each request
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
              //Returned JSON
            response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
              //converts JSON to string
            string responseJSONContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
              //deserializes string to list
            var jsonList = DeSerializeJsonString(responseJSONContent);
              //converts list to dataset. Bad name I know.
            dsTable = Foo_ConnectAPI.ExtentsionHelpers.ToDataSet<RootObject>(jsonList);
              //Returns the dataset                
            return dsTable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

       //deserializes the string to a list. Utilizes JSON.net. RootObject is a class that contains the get and set for the JSON elements

    public List<RootObject> DeSerializeJsonString(string jsonString)
    {
          //Initialized the List
        List<RootObject> list = new List<RootObject>();
          //json.net deserializes string
        list = (List<RootObject>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonString);

        return list;
    }
```

The RootObject contains the get set that will get the values of the JSON.

```
public class RootObject
{  
      //These string will be set to the elements within the JSON. Each one is directly mapped to the JSON elements.
      //This only takes into account a JSON that doesn't contain nested arrays
    public string EntityID { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    public string Address3 { get; set; }

}
```

The easiest way to create the above class(es) is to use [json2charp](http://www.json2csharp.com/) which will format it accordingly and also provide the correct datatypes.

The following is from another answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719280/3056507)
again it does not take into account nested JSON.

```
    internal static class ExtentsionHelpers
{
    public static DataSet ToDataSet<T>(this List<RootObject> list)
    {
        try
        {
            Type elementType = typeof(RootObject);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(t);

            try
            {
                //add a column to table for each public property on T
                foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Type ColType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propInfo.PropertyType) ?? propInfo.PropertyType;

                            t.Columns.Add(propInfo.Name, ColType);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                //go through each property on T and add each value to the table
                foreach (RootObject item in list)
                {
                    DataRow row = t.NewRow();

                    foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
                    {
                        row[propInfo.Name] = propInfo.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    }

                    t.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            insert.insertCategories(t);
            return ds.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            return null;
        }
    }
};
```

Then finally to insert the above dataset into a table with columns that were mapped to the JSON I utilized SQL bulk copy and the following class

```
public class insert
{ 
    public static string insertCategories(DataTable table)
    {     
        SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection();
          //As specified in the App.config/web.config file
        objConnection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ToString();

        try
        {                                 
            objConnection.Open();
            var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(objConnection.ConnectionString);

            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.foo";
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);

            return "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return "";
        }
        finally
        {
            objConnection.Close();
        }         
    }
};
```

So the above works to insert JSON from a webAPI into a database. This is something that I get to work. But by no means do I expect it to be perfect. If you have any improvements then please update it accordingly.

Comment: You should create your `HttpClient` and your `HttpResponse` inside a `using()` statement each to ensure proper, timely disposal and closing of the underlying streams.

Answer (score 0):

Sooner or later your code might brake if your server use another compression scheme like 'Brotli' with content-type: br

I have made a video to handle decompression in httpClient with the clientHandler:

[compression algos handled by httpClientHandler](https://youtu.be/6cUCA7jDavY)