# Getting an UTF-8 response with httpclient in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-runtime

I'm building a Windows Store app, but I'm stuck at getting a UTF-8 response from an API.

This is the code:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    Uri url = new Uri(BaseUrl + "/me/lists");

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    response.Dispose();
}
```

The `reponseString` always contains strange characters which should be accents like *é*, and I tried using a stream, but the API I found in some examples don't exist in Windows RT.

Edit: improved code, still same problem.

Comment: Are you completely sure API you are calling handles non-ASCII text correctly? (hard to guess from your code what you are calling)

Comment: It's not clear at all what the problem is you're describing. Are you expecting a UTF-8 response? Is the server sending one? Can you hit the web service directly using Fiddler to see what it's returning?

Comment: Is the Content-Type header of the response set to the correct value? Have you tried the method `_client.GetStringAsync(url)`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, in the Chrome REST Console I get a good UTF-8 response, accents are shown where they should be.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I don't know how to use Fiddler for HTTPS requests. But in the Chrome REST Console I see an UTF-8 response.

Comment: @cremor Tried that. Same problem :/

Comment: Are you perhaps calling a REST api in a .NET standard dll that is referenced by UWP? None of the answers here have helped me. The one marked as the answer definitely doesn't help.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Instead of using `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` directly you could use `response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync()` pointed by @Kiewic as follows:

```
var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
var byteArray = buffer.ToArray();
var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

This is working in my case and I guess that using UTF8 should solve most of the issues. Now go figure why there is no way to do this using `ReadAsStringAsync` :)

Comment: is that a typo? It seems like the method name is just repeated: "Instead of using response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() directly you could use response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()"

Comment: @superjos You're right, there was a typo, the method is ReadAsBufferAsync. I just fixed it.

Comment: I'm having this problem, but this doesn't fix my problem. My code works fine in .NET Core, but I am getting garbled characters in UWP.

Comment: ReadAsBufferAsync doesn't exist. maybe ReadAsByteArrayAsync?

Answer (score 8):

Solved it like this:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                var byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                return result;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the problem is that the response is zipped. If the content type is gzip, you will need decompress the response in to a string. Some servers do this to save bandwidth which is normally fine. In .NET Core and probably .NET Framework, this will automatically unzip the response. But this does not work in UWP. This seems like a glaring bug in UWP to me.

```
string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This thread gives a clear example of how to decompress the response:

[Compression/Decompression string with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343465/compression-decompression-string-with-c-sharp)

Comment: This solved it for me. Just to be sure before trying to decompress the response I disabled the "Accept-Encoding" header by commenting-out `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("*Accept-Encoding*", "gzip, deflate, br");` and it worked fine after that.

Comment: It boggles the mind that this is still a problem on UWP

Comment: solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27327208/2290188
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler)) //see update below
{
    // your code
}

Answer (score 3):

I like El Marchewko's approach of using an extension, but the code did not work for me. This did:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WannaSport.Data.Integration
{
    public static class HttpContentExtension
    {
        public static async Task<string> ReadAsStringUTF8Async(this HttpContent content)
        {
            return await content.ReadAsStringAsync(Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        public static async Task<string> ReadAsStringAsync(this HttpContent content, Encoding encoding)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader((await content.ReadAsStreamAsync()), encoding))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue in UWP. My code works fine in .NET Core, but I get totally garbled characters in UWP. I tried this exact code and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpClient` doesn't give you a lot of flexibility.

You can use a `HttpWebRequest` instead and get the raw bytes from the response using `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()`.

Comment: What about `Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so I'll have to add my thoughts here.

You could try to use `_client.GetStringAsync(url)` as @cremor suggested, and set your authentication headers using the `_client.DefaultRequestHeaders` property. 
Alternatively, you could also try to use the `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` method on the `response.Content` object and use `System.Text.Encoding` to decode that byte array to a UTF-8 string.

Comment: ReadAsByteArrayAsync is not available in WinRT

Comment: @SamuelDebruyn `response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` is supported in WinRT.

Comment: @Kiewic The only 3 options I get when I start typing response.Content.Read... are `ReadAsBufferAsync`, `ReadAsInputStreamAsync` and `ReadAsStringAsync`

Comment: Oh you are using Wondows.Web.Http.HttpClient, then ReadAsBuffer should work. you can convert a butter to a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

My approach using an Extension:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Windows.Web.Http;

    namespace yourfancyNamespace
    {
        public static class IHttpContentExtension
        {
            public static async Task<string> ReadAsStringUTF8Async(this IHttpContent content)
            {
                return await content.ReadAsStringAsync(Encoding.UTF8);
            }
            public static async Task<string> ReadAsStringAsync(this IHttpContent content, Encoding encoding)
            {
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader((await content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync()).AsStreamForRead(), encoding))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```