# C# .Net6 HTTPClient - Character problems

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem with some characters when I use HTTPCLient, where it would have to come 
 comes \u003cBR\u003e, I would have to solve this I have to use .Replace("\u003c", "<") .Replace("\u003e", ">")?

Am I using the following code?

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header,
                    headerAuthenticationValue);
                
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        var tmpStr = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())` <- no! [Read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) _"HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors."_

Comment: Anyhow. What is your actual problem? That the data you are receiving is not in the format you want is to be? I don't think it's an issue with HttpClient, but with the data source. It seems to be unicode , maybe you're missing some json serializer? Or some other decoder? What's the source?

Comment: Thanks for the using tip (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()).
I'm updating my code .Net Frameworks 4.7.2 to .Net 6 and before the information came correctly.
The text is:
Peças e Acessórios Originais ARNO<BR>Redutor Completo
And it's coming: 
Peças e Acessórios Originais ARNO\\u003cBR\\u003eRedutor Completo

Another thing that has changed is that before I was on Visual Studio 2019 and Windows10 and now I'm on Ubuntu with VSCode, I started the migration on Ubuntu, but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: How do you get the source? this looks like double encoding. Normally `\u003c` would resolve to a unicode character, but since the \ is escaped by an extra \, thus is not parsed correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting an UTF-8 response with httpclient in Windows Store apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649473/getting-an-utf-8-response-with-httpclient-in-windows-store-apps)

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving a string that contains escaped Unicode characters representing HTML characters. You can use [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=net-6.0):

```cs
var str = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("\u003cBR\u003e"); // returns <BR>
```

or in your case:

```cs
var tmpStr = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(await content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: `\u003c` is not a HTML character, but unicode. Furthermore, he is actually receiving `\\u003c`

Comment: It's the escaped unicode representation of the HTML character `<`, and using `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` correctly replaces it :) It's unclear if they receive `\u003c` (as stated in the question) or `\\u003c` (as stated in their comment).

Comment: IMHO it's like using the back-end of a screwdriver to drive in a nail... HtmlDecode is to decode a string that has been html-encoded, not to fix other issues that can be solved a better way.

Comment: I received \\u003c, the strange thing that when I use the code:
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add(header, headerAuthenticationValue);

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
 {                           
  var tmpStr = eader.ReadToEnd();
 }
}
In .Net Frameworks 4.7.2 it works.